# What process created this X11 window?

Tags: process, x11

Given an X11 window ID, is there a way to find the ID of the process that created it?

Of course this isn't always possible, for example if the window came over a TCP connection. For that case I'd like the IP and port associated with the remote end.

[The question was asked before on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131277/how-to-convert-a-x11-window-id-to-a-process-id), and a proposed method was to use the `_NET_WM_PID` property. But that's set by the application. Is there a way to do it if the application doesn't play nice?

Comment: Related: [PID from window ID/name](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/46621)

Comment: Just curious, did you run into any exception so far ? most common apps (libreoffice, vlc, konsole, thunderbird, firefox, emacs) correctly set their `_NET_WM_PID`.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Unless your X-server supports `XResQueryClientIds` from [X-Resource v1.2 extension](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/resourceproto/resproto.txt) I know no *easy* way to *reliably* request process ID. There're other ways however.

If you just have a window in front of you and don't know its ID yet — it's easy to find it out. Just open a terminal next to the window in question, run `xwininfo` there and click on that window. `xwininfo` will show you the window-id.

So let's assume you know a window-id, e.g. 0x1600045, and want to find, what's the process owning it.

The easiest way to check who that window belongs to is to run XKillClient for it i.e.:

```
xkill -id 0x1600045
```

and see which process just died. But only if you don't mind killing it of course!

Another easy but unreliable way is to check its `_NET_WM_PID` and `WM_CLIENT_MACHINE` properties:

```
xprop -id 0x1600045
```

That's what tools like `xlsclients` and [`xrestop`](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xrestop/) do.

Unfortunately this information may be incorrect not only because the process was evil and changed those, but also because it was buggy. For example after some firefox crash/restart I've seen orphaned windows (from flash plugin, I guess) with `_NET_WM_PID` pointing to a process, that died long time ago.

Alternative way is to run

```
xwininfo -root -tree
```

and check properties of parents of the window in question. That may also give you some hints about window origins.

But! While you may not find what process have created that window, there's still a way to find where that process have connected to X-server from. And that way is for real hackers. :)

The window-id 0x1600045 that you know with lower bits zeroed (i.e. 0x1600000) is a "client base". And all resource IDs, allocated for that client are "based" on it (0x1600001, 0x1600002, 0x1600003, etc). X-server stores information about its clients in clients[] array, and for each client its "base" is stored in clients[i]->clientAsMask variable. To find X-socket, corresponding to that client, you need to attach to X-server with `gdb`, walk over clients[] array, find client with that `clientAsMask` and print its socket descriptor, stored in ((OsCommPtr)(clients[i]->osPrivate))->fd.

There may be many X-clients connected, so in order to not check them all manually, let's use a gdb function:

```
define findclient
  set $ii = 0
  while ($ii < currentMaxClients)
    if (clients[$ii] != 0 && clients[$ii]->clientAsMask == $arg0 && clients[$ii]->osPrivate != 0)
      print ((OsCommPtr)(clients[$ii]->osPrivate))->fd
    end
    set $ii = $ii + 1
  end
end
```

When you find the socket, you can check, who's connected to it, and finally find the process.

**WARNING**: Do NOT attach gdb to X-server from INSIDE the X-server. gdb suspends the process it attaches to, so if you attach to it from inside X-session, you'll freeze your X-server and won't be able to interact with gdb. You must either switch to text terminal (`Ctrl+Alt+F2`) or connect to your machine over ssh.

### Example:

1. Find the PID of your X-server:

   ```
   $ ps ax | grep X
    1237 tty1     Ssl+  11:36 /usr/bin/X :0 vt1 -nr -nolisten tcp -auth /var/run/kdm/A:0-h6syCa
   ```
2. Window id is 0x1600045, so client base is 0x1600000. Attach to X-server and find client socket descriptor for that client base. You'll need debug information
   installed for X-server (-debuginfo package for rpm-distributions or -dbg package for deb's).

   ```
   $ sudo gdb
   (gdb) define findclient
   Type commands for definition of "findclient".
   End with a line saying just "end".
   >  set $ii = 0
   >  while ($ii < currentMaxClients)
    >   if (clients[$ii] != 0 && clients[$ii]->clientAsMask == $arg0 && clients[$ii]->osPrivate != 0)
     >     print ((OsCommPtr)(clients[$ii]->osPrivate))->fd
     >     end
    >   set $ii = $ii + 1
    >   end
   >  end
   (gdb) attach 1237
   (gdb) findclient 0x1600000
   $1 = 31
   (gdb) detach
   (gdb) quit
   ```
3. Now you know that client is connected to a server socket 31. Use `lsof` to find what that socket is:

   ```
   $ sudo lsof -n | grep 1237 | grep 31
   X        1237    root   31u   unix 0xffff810008339340       8512422 socket
   ```

   (here "X" is the process name, "1237" is its pid, "root" is the user it's running from, "31u" is a socket descriptor)

   There you may see that the client is connected over TCP, then you can go to the machine it's connected from and check `netstat -nap` there to find the process. But most probably you'll see a unix socket there, as shown above, which means it's a local client.
4. To find a pair for that unix socket you can use the [MvG's technique](https://serverfault.com/a/417946)
   (you'll also need debug information for your kernel installed):

   ```
   $ sudo gdb -c /proc/kcore
   (gdb) print ((struct unix_sock*)0xffff810008339340)->peer
   $1 = (struct sock *) 0xffff810008339600
   (gdb) quit
   ```
5. Now that you know client socket, use `lsof` to find PID holding it:

   ```
   $ sudo lsof -n | grep 0xffff810008339600
   firefox  7725  username  146u   unix 0xffff810008339600       8512421 socket
   ```

That's it. The process keeping that window is "firefox" with process-id 7725

---

**2017 Edit**: There are more options now as seen at [Who's got the other end of this unix socketpair?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16300). With Linux 3.3 or above and with `lsof` 4.89 or above, you can replace points 3 to 5 above with:

```
lsof +E -a -p 1237 -d 31
```

to find out who's at the other end of the socket on fd 31 of the X-server process with ID 1237.

Comment: Welcome the the Unix and Linux Stack Exchange! Your answer to this question is excellent. I hope you come back to answer more questions.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer to this question. Regarding the option to kill the process using xkill, three things: 1. Is there a way to monitor either process deaths in the OS, or maybe trace the system call to kill the process? Figuring out which process died manually seems difficult.

Comment: 2. I'm sure xkill internally must be able to find out the process ID that spawned the window in order to kill it. Maybe someone could add a flag to print instead of killing the process?

Comment: 3. The `xwininfo -root -tree` suggestion was very helpful for me and in general, I think it should be moved higher in the answer

Comment: That's a very complete answer and it turned out to be very helpful.

Comment: instead of `xwininfo` and then `xprop -id …` you can just run `xprop` without parameters, and click on the window. It results in the same info.

Answer (score 48):

`xdotool` didn't work for me. This did:

Run

```
xprop _NET_WM_PID
```

and click on the window.

This is based on [Finding PID of an X window at Linux Questions](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/advanced-question-finding-pid-of-an-x-window-328983/).

Comment: Works for me when plugging in my Iphone brought up a non-responsive window prompt.

Comment: Useful for evince that sometimes hung completely. `kill $(xprop _NET_WM_PID|cut -d " " -f 3)`

Comment: This is what I was looking for, xkill flow

Answer (score 17):

If you have [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) installed, then

```
xdotool selectwindow getwindowpid
```

followed by clicking on the window in question will return the PID.

(There are other ways of selecting the window in question, e.g., if you have its window ID you can just do `xdotool getwindowpid <number>`. You can also select by name or class, etc.)

I do think this requires some playing nice on behalf of the WM. I haven't experimented much, or needed to.

Comment: `xdo_getwinprop(xdo, window, atom_NET_WM_PID, &nitems, &type, &size)` ⇒ it's just a shell wrapper to read `_NET_WM_PID` (useful, but not what I asked for).

Answer (score 13):

The `_NET_WM_PID` isn't set by the window manager (as just another X11 client, how would it know?).

Instead, compliant X11 clients (applications) are expected to set `_NET_WM_PID` and `WM_CLIENT_MACHINE` on their own windows.  Assuming a well-behaved application, this will be true whether a window manager is running or not.

If `WM_CLIENT_MACHINE` is your own hostname, then the PID should be meaningful.
Otherwise, "I'd like the IP and port associated with the remote end" — I'm not sure what that means.  For example, if you have an ssh session open with X forwarding enabled, windows opened by forwarded apps will be marked with remote PID and hostname, but you don't necessarily have any way to connect back to that remote host.

Comment: `_NET_WM_PID` is set by the application: right, that does make more sense! But it's not the X11 protocol, it's the relatively recent [FreeDesktop](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s05.html) specification.

Comment: In the ssh case, as far as the X server is concerned, this is a local connection from the sshd process. Though `_NET_WM_PID` seems to be set to the remote PID and `WM_CLIENT_MACHINE` to the remote connection (tested with xterm).

Answer (score 5):

I was able to use the `xdotool` under Ubuntu 11.04 beta, but `selectwindow` was not a valid command, I had to hack a script with:

```
$ while true; do sleep 1; xdotool getactivewindow; done
```

then watch the window ID go by while I selected the window I wanted, then decoded the responsible PID with:

```
$ xdotool getwindowpid <the-window-id>
```