# Find creator of resource in X

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xorg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What process created this X11 window?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5478/what-process-created-this-x11-window)

Recently I've been bugged by a mysterious invisible window in X on my Ubuntu machine.
It takes the form of an always-top-most window with absolutely nothing showing; no window border, no content, no nothing. That means that entire area of the screen is now unusable with any pointer, since the window captures all events in it's context - I can't even click on the desktop in that area !

As you might have guess this is rather annoying, and I want to get rid of it permanently.
However, running `xwininfo` on it gives the following:

```
xwininfo: Window id: 0x1601b9f (has no name)
[...]
Map State: IsViewable
Override Redirect State: yes
Corners:  +395+315  -383+315  -383-263  +395-263
-geometry 502x222+395+315
```

So, I've got an ID, but no name. This fortunately means I can kill it with `xkill`, but unfortunately means I have no idea what created it.

So what I'm looking for is some advice or help finding a way to identify the root and cause of this window.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: For future reference, the one-liner I'm using to kill the window: ID=`xwininfo | grep -oP "0x[0-9a-fA-F]{4,8} "`; xkill -id $ID

Comment: If you want a one-liner, at least do it like this: `xkill -id $(xwininfo | grep -oP "0x[0-9a-fA-F]{4,8} ")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture the output of `ps -eo pid,cmd` to a file, then kill the offending window, repeat the `ps`, and see what changed:

```
ps -eo pid,cmd >/tmp/ps1
ID=`xwininfo | grep -oP "0x[0-9a-fA-F]{4,8} "`; xkill -id $ID
ps -eo pid,cmd >/tmp/ps2
diff /tmp/ps{1,2}
```

Kind of a brute-force method, but it should work.

Comment: I initially tried something along that line but with `pstree` instead, but I couldn't actually see any difference in the two outputs.
But I will try your suggestion next time I see the problem, and see if this works instead.
Thanks

Comment: Ok, so the bug finally re-appeared, and I was able to try this solution.
It's not perfect since you have to account for processes spawned by running the above, but it succeeded in giving me a hint what might be going on here.
Again, thanks.