# Who's got the other end of this unix socketpair?

Tags: process, socket, open-files, lsof

**I want to determine which process has the other end of a UNIX socket.**

Specifically, I'm asking about one that was created with `socketpair()`, though the problem is the same for any UNIX socket.

I have a program `parent` which creates a `socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, fds)`, and `fork()`s.  The parent process closes `fds[1]` and keeps `fds[0]` to communicate. The child does the opposite, `close(fds[0]); s=fds[1]`.  Then the child `exec()`s another program, `child1`.  The two can communicate back and forth via this socketpair.

Now, let's say I know who `parent` is, but I want to figure out who `child1` is.  How do I do this?

There are several tools at my disposal, but none can tell me which process is on the other end of the socket. I have tried:

- `lsof -c progname`
- `lsof -c parent -c child1`
- `ls -l /proc/$(pidof server)/fd`
- `cat /proc/net/unix`

Basically, I can see the two sockets, and everything about them, but cannot tell that they are connected. I am trying to determine which FD in the parent is communicating with which child process.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Since kernel 3.3, it is possible using [`ss`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ss.8.html) or `lsof-4.89` or above — see [Stéphane Chazelas's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/190606/).

In older versions, according to the author of `lsof`, it was impossible to find this out: the Linux kernel does not expose this information. Source: [2003 thread on comp.unix.admin](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.unix.admin/browse_thread/thread/8992ecab97477722/c865cc9809c06bdc).

The number shown in `/proc/$pid/fd/$fd` is the socket's inode number in the virtual socket filesystem. When you create a pipe or socket pair, each end successively receives an inode number. The numbers are attributed sequentially, so there is a high probability that the numbers differ by 1, but this is not guaranteed (either because the first socket was *N* and *N*+1 was already in use due to wrapping, or because some other thread was scheduled between the two inode allocations and that thread created some inodes too).

I checked the [definition of `socketpair` in kernel 2.6.39](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.39/net/socket.c#L1335), and the two ends of the socket are not correlated except by the type-specific [`socketpair` method](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.39/include/linux/net.h#L160). For unix sockets, that's [`unix_socketpair` in `net/unix/af_unix.c`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.39/net/unix/af_unix.c#L1223).

Comment: Thanks @Gillles. I do recall reading something about that a while back, but was unable to find it again.  I may just have to go writing a patch for /proc/net/unix.

Comment: And yes, I'd made that observation with the increasing inode numbers, and currently that's what I'm working with.  However, as you noted, it is not guaranteed. The process I'm looking at has at least 40 open unix sockets, and I saw one instance where the N+1 did not hold true. Bummer.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I checked [the definition of `socketpair`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.39/net/socket.c#L1335), and the two ends of the socket are not correlated except by the type-specific [`socketpair` method](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.39/include/linux/net.h#L160). For unix sockets, that's [`unix_socketpair` in `net/unix/af_unix.c](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.39/net/unix/af_unix.c#L1223). It would be nice to have this information for pipes, too.

Answer (score 61):

> <sup>***Note**: I now maintain a `lsof` wrapper that combines both approaches described here and also adds information for peers of loopback TCP connections at https://github.com/stephane-chazelas/misc-scripts/blob/master/lsofc*</sup>

### Linux-3.3 and above.

On Linux, since kernel version 3.3 (and provided the [`UNIX_DIAG`](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/UNIX_DIAG.html) feature is built in the kernel), the peer of a given unix domain socket (includes socketpairs) can be obtained using a new *netlink* based API.

`lsof` since version 4.89 can make use of that API:

```
lsof +E -aUc Xorg
```

Will list all the Unix domain sockets that have a process whose name starts with `Xorg` at either end in a format similar to:

```
Xorg       2777       root   56u  unix 0xffff8802419a7c00      0t0   34036 @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 type=STREAM ->INO=33273 4120,xterm,3u
```

If your version of `lsof` is too old, there are a few more options.

The `ss` utility (from `iproute2`) makes use of that same API to retrieve and display information on the list of unix domain sockets on the system including peer information.

The sockets are identified by their *inode number*. Note that it's not related to the filesystem inode of the socket file.

For instance in:

```
$ ss -x
[...]
u_str  ESTAB    0    0   @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 3435997     * 3435996
```

it says that socket 3435997 (that was bound to the ABSTRACT socket `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0`) is connected with socket 3435996. The `-p` option can tell you which process(es) have that socket open. It does that by doing some `readlink`s on `/proc/$pid/fd/*`, so it can only do that  on processes you own (unless you're `root`). For instance here:

```
$ sudo ss -xp
[...]
u_str  ESTAB  0  0  @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 3435997 * 3435996 users:(("Xorg",pid=3080,fd=83))
[...]
$ sudo ls -l /proc/3080/fd/23
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Mar 12 16:34 /proc/3080/fd/83 -> socket:[3435997]
```

To find out what process(es) has 3435996, you can look up its own entry in the output of `ss -xp`:

```
$ ss -xp | awk '$6 == 3435996'
u_str  ESTAB  0  0  * 3435996  * 3435997 users:(("xterm",pid=29215,fd=3))
```

You could also use this script as a wrapper around `lsof` to easily show the relevant information there:

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl
# lsof wrapper to add peer information for unix domain socket.
# Needs Linux 3.3 or above and CONFIG_UNIX_DIAG enabled.

# retrieve peer and direction information from ss
my (%peer, %dir);
open SS, '-|', 'ss', '-nexa';
while (<SS>) {
  if (/\s(\d+)\s+\*\s+(\d+) ([<-]-[->])$/) {
    $peer{$1} = $2;
    $dir{$1} = $3;
  }
}
close SS;

# Now get info about processes tied to sockets using lsof
my (%fields, %proc);
open LSOF, '-|', 'lsof', '-nPUFpcfin';
while (<LSOF>) {
  if (/(.)(.*)/) {
    $fields{$1} = $2;
    if ($1 eq 'n') {
      $proc{$fields{i}}->{"$fields{c},$fields{p}" .
      ($fields{n} =~ m{^([@/].*?)( type=\w+)?$} ? ",$1" : "")} = "";
    }
  }
}
close LSOF;

# and finally process the lsof output
open LSOF, '-|', 'lsof', @ARGV;
while (<LSOF>) {
  chomp;
  if (/\sunix\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(\d+)\s/) {
    my $peer = $peer{$1};
    if (defined($peer)) {
      $_ .= $peer ?
            " ${dir{$1}} $peer\[" . (join("|", keys%{$proc{$peer}})||"?") . "]" :
            "[LISTENING]";
    }
  }
  print "$_\n";
}
close LSOF or exit(1);
```

For example:

```
$ sudo that-lsof-wrapper -ad3 -p 29215
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
xterm   29215 stephane    3u  unix 0xffff8800a07da4c0      0t0 3435996 type=STREAM <-> 3435997[Xorg,3080,@/tmp/.X11-unix/X0]
```

### Before linux-3.3

The old Linux API to retrieve unix socket information is via the `/proc/net/unix` text file. It lists all the Unix domain sockets (including socketpairs). The first field in there (if not hidden to non-superusers with the `kernel.kptr_restrict` sysctl parameter) as [already explained by @Totor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/189709) contains the kernel address of a `unix_sock` structure that contains a `peer` field pointing to the corresponding *peer* `unix_sock`. It's also what `lsof` outputs for the `DEVICE` column on a Unix socket.

Now getting the value of that `peer` field means being able to read kernel memory and know the offset of that `peer` field with regards to the `unix_sock` address.

Several [`gdb`-based](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/189709) and [`systemtap`-based](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/189944) solutions have already been given but they require `gdb`/`systemtap` and Linux kernel debug symbols for the running kernel being installed which is generally not the case on production systems.

Hardcoding the offset is not really an option as that varies with kernel version.

Now we can use a heuristic approach at determining the offset: have our tool create a dummy `socketpair` (then we know the address of both peers), and search for the address of the *peer* around the memory at the other end to determine the offset.

Here is a proof-of-concept script that does just that using `perl` (successfully tested with kernel 2.4.27 and 2.6.32 on i386 and 3.13 and 3.16 on amd64). Like above, it works as a wrapper around `lsof`:

For example:

```
$ that-lsof-wrapper -aUc nm-applet
COMMAND    PID     USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF  NODE NAME
nm-applet 4183 stephane    4u  unix 0xffff8800a055eb40      0t0 36888 type=STREAM -> 0xffff8800a055e7c0[dbus-daemon,4190,@/tmp/dbus-AiBCXOnuP6]
nm-applet 4183 stephane    7u  unix 0xffff8800a055e440      0t0 36890 type=STREAM -> 0xffff8800a055e0c0[Xorg,3080,@/tmp/.X11-unix/X0]
nm-applet 4183 stephane    8u  unix 0xffff8800a05c1040      0t0 36201 type=STREAM -> 0xffff8800a05c13c0[dbus-daemon,4118,@/tmp/dbus-yxxNr1NkYC]
nm-applet 4183 stephane   11u  unix 0xffff8800a055d080      0t0 36219 type=STREAM -> 0xffff8800a055d400[dbus-daemon,4118,@/tmp/dbus-yxxNr1NkYC]
nm-applet 4183 stephane   12u  unix 0xffff88022e0dfb80      0t0 36221 type=STREAM -> 0xffff88022e0df800[dbus-daemon,2268,/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket]
nm-applet 4183 stephane   13u  unix 0xffff88022e0f80c0      0t0 37025 type=STREAM -> 0xffff88022e29ec00[dbus-daemon,2268,/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket]
```

Here's the script:

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl
# wrapper around lsof to add peer information for Unix
# domain sockets. needs lsof, and superuser privileges.
# Copyright Stephane Chazelas 2015, public domain.
# example: sudo this-lsof-wrapper -aUc Xorg
use Socket;

open K, "<", "/proc/kcore" or die "open kcore: $!";
read K, $h, 8192 # should be more than enough
 or die "read kcore: $!";

# parse ELF header
my ($t,$o,$n) = unpack("x4Cx[C19L!]L!x[L!C8]S", $h);
$t = $t == 1 ? "L3x4Lx12" : "Lx4QQx8Qx16"; # program header ELF32 or ELF64
my @headers = unpack("x$o($t)$n",$h);

# read data from kcore at given address (obtaining file offset from ELF
# @headers)
sub readaddr {
  my @h = @headers;
  my ($addr, $length) = @_;
  my $offset;
  while (my ($t, $o, $v, $s) = splice @h, 0, 4) {
    if ($addr >= $v && $addr < $v + $s) {
      $offset = $o + $addr - $v;
      if ($addr + $length - $v > $s) {
        $length = $s - ($addr - $v);
      }
      last;
    }
  }
  return undef unless defined($offset);
  seek K, $offset, 0 or die "seek kcore: $!";
  my $ret;
  read K, $ret, $length or die "read($length) kcore \@$offset: $!";
  return $ret;
}

# create a dummy socketpair to try find the offset in the
# kernel structure
socketpair(Rdr, Wtr, AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, PF_UNSPEC)
 or die "socketpair: $!";
$r = readlink("/proc/self/fd/" . fileno(Rdr)) or die "readlink Rdr: $!";
$r =~ /\[(\d+)/; $r = $1;
$w = readlink("/proc/self/fd/" . fileno(Wtr)) or die "readlink Wtr: $!";
$w =~ /\[(\d+)/; $w = $1;
# now $r and $w contain the socket inodes of both ends of the socketpair
die "Can't determine peer offset" unless $r && $w;

# get the inode->address mapping
open U, "<", "/proc/net/unix" or die "open unix: $!";
while (<U>) {
  if (/^([0-9a-f]+):(?:\s+\S+){5}\s+(\d+)/) {
    $addr{$2} = hex $1;
  }
}
close U;

die "Can't determine peer offset" unless $addr{$r} && $addr{$w};

# read 2048 bytes starting at the address of Rdr and hope to find
# the address of Wtr referenced somewhere in there.
$around = readaddr $addr{$r}, 2048;
my $offset = 0;
my $ptr_size = length(pack("L!",0));
my $found;
for (unpack("L!*", $around)) {
  if ($_ == $addr{$w}) {
    $found = 1;
    last;
  }
  $offset += $ptr_size;
}
die "Can't determine peer offset" unless $found;

my %peer;
# now retrieve peer for each socket
for my $inode (keys %addr) {
  $peer{$addr{$inode}} = unpack("L!", readaddr($addr{$inode}+$offset,$ptr_size));
}
close K;

# Now get info about processes tied to sockets using lsof
my (%fields, %proc);
open LSOF, '-|', 'lsof', '-nPUFpcfdn';
while (<LSOF>) {
  if (/(.)(.*)/) {
    $fields{$1} = $2;
    if ($1 eq 'n') {
      $proc{hex($fields{d})}->{"$fields{c},$fields{p}" .
      ($fields{n} =~ m{^([@/].*?)( type=\w+)?$} ? ",$1" : "")} = "";
    }
  }
}
close LSOF;

# and finally process the lsof output
open LSOF, '-|', 'lsof', @ARGV;
while (<LSOF>) {
  chomp;
  for my $addr (/0x[0-9a-f]+/g) {
    $addr = hex $addr;
    my $peer = $peer{$addr};
    if (defined($peer)) {
      $_ .= $peer ?
            sprintf(" -> 0x%x[", $peer) . join("|", keys%{$proc{$peer}}) . "]" :
            "[LISTENING]";
      last;
    }
  }
  print "$_\n";
}
close LSOF or exit(1);
```

Comment: Is this part of anything bigger? You seem to have put a lot of effort into this lately.

Comment: @mikeserv, that's a follow-up on [that comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16300#comment317366_189709). Not being able to find the other end of unix sockets is something that has always annoyed me (often when trying to find X clients and there was [a recent question about that](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/189545)). I'll try and see if a similar approach can be used [for pseudo-terminals](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/136662) and suggest those to the `lsof` author.

Comment: I still can't believe this isn't provided by the kernel itself! I should really submit a patch, if for nothing else but to discover why it doesn't already exist.

Comment: does `ss` not do this? It's kind of over my head, but `ss -px` lists a lot of unix sockets with peer information like: `users: ("nacl_helper",pid=18992,fd=6),("chrome",pid=18987,fd=6),("chrome",pid=18975,fd=5))
u_str ESTAB\t0\t0\t/run/dbus/system_bus_socket 8760\t\t* 15068` and the column headings are... `State\tRecv-Q\tSend-Q\tLocal Address:Port\tPeer Address:Port`

Comment: Also, if I do `lsof -c terminology` I can see `terminolo 12731\tmikeserv\t12u\tunix\t0xffff880600e82680\t0t0\t1312426\ttype=STREAM` but if I do `ss -px | grep terminology` I get: `u_str\tESTAB\t0\t0\t* 1312426\t*1315046\tusers:(("terminology",pid=12731,fd=12))`

Comment: @mikeserv, it looks like it does indeed! It seems I've been wasting a lot of time lately...

Comment: @mikeserv, the `ss` man page even has an example to list the X server clients! `ss -x src /tmp/.X11-unix/*` (doesn't work for me though)

Comment: Hmm... So it looks like `ss` is printing only the *Node* where `lsof` does the device name as well.. But if I do: `ss -px | grep terminology` to get that 1312426 *Node* again, and then after - `ss -px | grep 1315046` to search for the peer end it prints: `u_str\tESTAB\t0\t0\t@/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 1315046\t* 1312426`. It seems to be inline with the `man` page, which gives this example usage: `ss -x src /tmp/.X11-unix/*` *Find all local processes connected to `X` server.*

Comment: You pointed me back to that pty thing - and I remember looking at `ss` then *(and understanding even less then)* but it just kind of rung a bell.

Comment: The `ss -x src /tmp/...` does work here... I wonder what the difference would be? There's also an option for listing `-m`emory usage, but that doesn't reveal much for me, though. Still, the reverse `grep` thing pulled it in too. Hmmm... maybe try the `man` example w/ `-p` as well? That seems to be a little more informative. Oh. You know - I'm probably running usermode X as well - since 1.16 *(or whatever that version number was)* which might make it easier for me to do introspection. Most X servers are probably still superuser. I wonder if `ss` doesn't want to show you root info?

Comment: @mikeserv, On the systems I've tried, either `ss -x src /tmp/...` gives me all non-listening sockets (the filter doesn't filter) or it doesn't give me the peer. I can parse the output of `ss -x;ss -lx` though (not reliably for sockets with spaces or newlines)

Comment: If I add `-e` I also get these little arrows like `<->` or `<--` or `-->`. The `<--` and `-->` *(at a glance)* seem to occur only alongside entries which also list filenames. Do you think that is relevant at all? Strike that - That was a pretty weak glance. But it does seem that the `@` begins a pathname to a socket proper. And at least all of the pathnames appear to be fully qualified - the `/` slashes might be useful.

Comment: @mikeserv, not the best documented piece of software, is it? From the source, looks like those arrows are to indicate which direction of the socket is shutdown.

Comment: Stephane, actually, it's got *this huge* trove of docs. It's a member of the... iproute2 suite. Ok, that was from memory and wrong. But there is this: `cat /usr/share/doc/iproute2/ss.html`

Comment: Well, I give up on it - I still don't understand what it's all about really. Anyway, this does look interesting though - its seems to list only those *users* with something in (Receive|Send)Q: `ss -px src '/tmp/.X11*/*' | grep -v '^[^0-9]*0 *0 '`

Comment: I don't get it guys, if I do `ss -px | grep mysql` I still cannot link `mysql` with `mysqld` even if they both appear in the list (kernel 3.2).

Comment: @Totor, 3.2 would be too old. The feature was added in [this commit](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/commit/?id=ac02be8d96af9f66a4de86781ee9facc2dff99d4), first released in 3.3 AFAICT.

Comment: It looks like you're jumping from `long` to `long` to find the `peer` offset but how can you be sure that `peer` is on a `long` boundary?

Comment: @Totor, I did consider that point. My understanding would be that, since those point to structures (that contain pointers), they would be pointersize-aligned. See [there](http://lwn.net/Articles/260832/) and [there](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/unaligned-memory-access.txt) for more details.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks for the link. More accurately, it says that if you're looking for a N bytes value, you will find it on a N bytes address boundary (the compiler takes care of alignment).

Comment: @Totor that doesn't mean an 8 byte struct will be 8 byte aligned. An 8 byte long will be 8 byte aligned within the struct and such a struct at least 8 byte aligned. on the systems I've looked at, unix_sock were 64 byte aligned on 64 bit systems and 256 byte aligned on 32 bit ones

Comment: @mikeserv, the `ss` filter issue seems to have been fixed very recently in http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.linux.network/351180

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22040/discussion-between-totor-and-stephane-chazelas).

Comment: @mikeserv I tried `ss -px | grep mysql` with iproute 3.16 on a 3.13.1 kernel. Still can't link the client and the server sockets. Is it only working with `lsof` or doesn't it work at all?

Comment: @Totor - not as far as I know, but I'll tell you, you're probably not asking the right guy. I have only the faintest idea about what a socket even does. Still, though, is the `mysql` socket owned by you? I want to believe that `ss` wouldn't reveal privileged information to you. I wonder what I have that could be comparable...

Comment: @Totor - actually the chrome thing from earlier is probably closest - `chrome`'s processes are run in namespaced containers - and it maintains its own database. You can get information about a running process by referencing a `src` socket file *(maybe)* and you can `grep` for pid. I just cross-referenced `lsof` because that seemed to be the thread of things here. Anyway, it might help. Also there's this crappy doc: `cat /usr/share/doc/iproute2/ss.html`. *(the `ip` docs are **far and away** better done)*.

Comment: @mikeserv sorry, I didn't have `UNIX_DIAG` enabled in my kernel. Now I have, and indeed, when I use `ss -px`, the Peer column gives me an ID (inode number?) that is the same ID as the Local column on the other side of the socket. It works.

Comment: @Totor - don't apologize - I wasn't aware until now that it was a requirement. Thank you. Still though, I'm not entirely certain it does work, or, really, what work it *should do*. But Stéphane seems to think it works, and, based on my past year hanging around this website, I'd say that it's probably a pretty good indicator. It's why there's no answer here from me - and there isn't likely to be. I don't really understand what is wanted - I don't know the difference really between a socket or a pty *(line discipline?)*. I know I like to use ptys, and never had occasion to use a socket pair.

Comment: @mikeserv I updated [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16300/whos-got-the-other-end-of-this-unix-socketpair#189709) accordingly.

Comment: @Totor - I know. I upvoted accordingly. Thanks again, by the way.

Comment: That's pretty cool - looks you chunked out the last block of code to make up the majority of the top script. But didn't do you have some q/a thing on Perl's `<>`? Is it better now? I seem to remember it was a security thing...

Comment: @mikeserv, I made it a wrapper around lsof directly as it's mostly only going to be useful to process lsof output anyway. `<>` is a dangerous feature. It's useful in that you can do `perl -ne 'some processing' 'cmd|'` to do some processing on the output of `cmd`, but that becomes a problem when you do `perl -ne 'some processing' -- *` and can't guarantee file names won't end in `|`. [Details there](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/170013). Not really a concern here.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas sorry, continuing a very old chat [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47522/structures-alignment-in-memory). :)

Answer (score 11):

## Since kernel 3.3

You [can](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?id=ac02be8d96af9f66a4de86781ee9facc2dff99d4) [now](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/iproute2/iproute2.git/commit/misc/ss.c?id=dfbaa90dec05d3798ad845db20e1b273ffcfcf0a) get this information with [`ss`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ss.8.html):

```
# ss -xp
```

Now you can see in the `Peer` column an ID (inode number) which corresponds to another ID in the `Local` column. Matching IDs are the two ends of a socket.

<sup>Note: The `UNIX_DIAG` option must be enabled in your kernel.</sup>

## Before kernel 3.3

Linux didn't expose this information to userland.

However, by **looking into kernel memory**, we can access this information.

*Note: This answer does so by using `gdb`, however, please see [@StéphaneChazelas' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16300/whos-got-the-other-end-of-this-unix-socketpair#190606) which is more elaborated in this regard.*

```
# lsof | grep whatever
mysqld 14450 (...) unix 0xffff8801011e8280 (...) /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
mysqld 14450 (...) unix 0xffff8801011e9600 (...) /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

There is 2 different sockets, 1 listening and 1 established. The hexa number is the address to the corresponding kernel [`unix_sock` structure](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/net/af_unix.h?id=v3.19#n51), having a `peer` attribute being the address of *the other end of the socket* (also a `unix_sock` structure instance).

Now we can use `gdb` to find the `peer` within kernel memory:

```
# gdb /usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-3.2.0-4-amd64 /proc/kcore
(gdb) print ((struct unix_sock*)0xffff8801011e9600)->peer
$1 = (struct sock *) 0xffff880171f078c0

# lsof | grep 0xffff880171f078c0
mysql 14815 (...) unix 0xffff880171f078c0 (...) socket
```

Here you go, the other end of the socket is held by `mysql`, PID 14815.

Your kernel must be compiled with `KCORE_ELF` to use `/proc/kcore`. Also, you need a version of your kernel image with debugging symbols. On Debian 7, `apt-get install linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64-dbg` will provide this file.

### No need for the debuggable kernel image...

If you don't have (or don't want to keep) the debugging kernel image on the system, you can give `gdb` the memory offset to "manually" access the `peer` value. This offset value usually differ with kernel version or architecture.

On my kernel, I know the offset is 680 bytes, that is 85 times 64 bits. So I can do:

```
# gdb /boot/vmlinux-3.2.0-4-amd64 /proc/kcore
(gdb) print ((void**)0xffff8801011e9600)[85]
$1 = (void *) 0xffff880171f078c0
```

Voilà, same result as above.

If you have the same kernel running on several machine, it is easier to use this variant because you don't need the debug image, only the offset value.

To (easily) discover this offset value at first, you do need the debug image:

```
$ pahole -C unix_sock /usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-3.2.0-4-amd64
struct unix_sock {
  (...)
  struct sock *              peer;                 /*   680     8 */
  (...)
}
```

Here you go, 680 bytes, this is 85 x 64 bits, or 170 x 32 bits.

<sup>Most of the credit for this answer goes to [MvG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897662/identify-other-end-of-a-unix-domain-socket-connection/11900231#11900231).</sup>

Comment: Another approach to retrieve the offset could be to create a socketpair, identify the corresponding entries in /proc/net/unix based on inode numbers from readlinks on /proc/pif/fd/*, and scan memory around the address of one socket for the address of the other. That could make for a reasonably portable (accross Linux versions and architectures) that could be implemented by lsof itself. I'll try to come up with a PoC.

Comment: I've now added [such a PoC](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/190606) which seems to work well on the systems I've tested.

Answer (score 9):

[Erkki Seppala actually has a tool](http://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/ikizs/utility_to_list_the_other_end_of_a_given_unix/c24r40d) that retrieves this information from the Linux kernel with gdb.. It's available [here](http://www.modeemi.fi/~flux/software/list-unix-sockets.tar.gz).

Comment: Very useful information! Even if the tool didn't work out of the box for me (it caused a kernel Oops), the idea helped me to identify the other end. I [described my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11900231/1468366) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5):

> This solution, though working, is of limited interest since if you have a recent-enough systemtap, chances are you'll have a recent-enough kernel where you can use [`ss` based](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/190606) [approaches](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/189709), and if you're on an older kernel, [that other solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/190606), though more *hacky* is more likely to work and doesn't require addition software.
>
> Still useful as a demonstration of how to use `systemtap` for this kind of task.

If on a recent Linux system with a working systemtap (1.8 or newer), you could use the script below to post-process the output of `lsof`:

For example:

```
$ lsof -aUc nm-applet | sudo that-script
COMMAND    PID     USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF  NODE NAME
nm-applet 4183 stephane    4u  unix 0xffff8800a055eb40      0t0 36888 type=STREAM -> 0xffff8800a055e7c0[dbus-daemon,4190,@/tmp/dbus-AiBCXOnuP6]
nm-applet 4183 stephane    7u  unix 0xffff8800a055e440      0t0 36890 type=STREAM -> 0xffff8800a055e0c0[Xorg,3080,@/tmp/.X11-unix/X0]
nm-applet 4183 stephane    8u  unix 0xffff8800a05c1040      0t0 36201 type=STREAM -> 0xffff8800a05c13c0[dbus-daemon,4118,@/tmp/dbus-yxxNr1NkYC]
nm-applet 4183 stephane   11u  unix 0xffff8800a055d080      0t0 36219 type=STREAM -> 0xffff8800a055d400[dbus-daemon,4118,@/tmp/dbus-yxxNr1NkYC]
nm-applet 4183 stephane   12u  unix 0xffff88022e0dfb80      0t0 36221 type=STREAM -> 0xffff88022e0df800[dbus-daemon,2268,/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket]
nm-applet 4183 stephane   13u  unix 0xffff88022e0f80c0      0t0 37025 type=STREAM -> 0xffff88022e29ec00[dbus-daemon,2268,/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket]
```

(if you see 0x0000000000000000 above instead of 0xffff..., it's because the `kernel.kptr_restrict` sysctl parameter is set on your system which causes kernel pointers to be hidden from non-privileged processes, in which case you'll need to run `lsof` as root to get a meaningful result).

This script doesn't make any attempt to cope with socket file names with newline characters, but nor does `lsof` (nor does `lsof` cope with blanks or colons).

`systemtap` here is used to dump the address and peer address of all the `unix_sock` structures in the `unix_socket_table` hash in the kernel.

Only tested on Linux 3.16 amd64 with systemtap 2.6, and 3.13 with 2.3.

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl
# meant to process lsof output to try and find the peer of a given
# unix domain socket. Needs a working systemtap, lsof, and superuser
# privileges. Copyright Stephane Chazelas 2015, public domain.
# Example: lsof -aUc X | sudo this-script
open STAP, '-|', 'stap', '-e', q{
  probe begin {
    offset = &@cast(0, "struct sock")->__sk_common->skc_node;
    for (i = 0; i < 512; i++) 
      for (p = @var("unix_socket_table@net/unix/af_unix.c")[i]->first;
           p;
           p=@cast(p, "struct hlist_node")->next
          ) {
        sock = p - offset;
        printf("%p %p\n", sock, @cast(sock, "struct unix_sock")->peer);
    }
    exit()
  }
};  
my %peer;
while (<STAP>) {
  chomp;
  my ($a, $b) = split;
  $peer{$a} = $b;
}
close STAP;

my %f, %addr;
open LSOF, '-|', 'lsof', '-nPUFpcfdn';
while (<LSOF>) {
  if (/(.)(.*)/) {
    $f{$1} = $2;
    if ($1 eq 'n') {
      $addr{$f{d}}->{"$f{c},$f{p}" . ($f{n} =~ m{^([@/].*?)( type=\w+)?$} ? ",$1" : "")} = "";
    }
  }
}
close LSOF;

while (<>) {
  chomp;
  for my $addr (/0x[0-9a-f]+/g) {
    my $peer = $peer{$addr};
    if (defined($peer)) {
      $_ .= $peer eq '0x0' ?
            "[LISTENING]" :
            " -> $peer\[" . join("|", keys%{$addr{$peer}}) . "]";
      last;
    }
  }
  print "$_\n";
}
```

Comment: `parse error: unknown statistic operator @var`: am I missing something?

Comment: @Totor, `@var` was added in  systemtap 1.8, 2012-06-17 (latest is 2.7)

Answer (score 3):

4.89 of lsof supports displaying endpoint options.

Quoted from lsof.8:

```
+|-E +E specifies that process intercommunication channels should be
     displayed with endpoint information and the channels
     of the endpoints should also be displayed.  Currently
     only pipe on Linux is implemented.

     Endpoint information is displayed in the NAME column
     in the form "PID,cmd,FDmode".  PID is the endpoint
     process ID; cmd is the endpoint process command; FD is
     the endpoint file's descriptor; and mode is the
     endpoint file's access mode.  Multiple occurrences of
     this information can appear in a file's NAME column.

     -E specfies that Linux pipe files should only be
     displayed with endpoint information.
```

Example of output:

```
mozStorag 21535 22254  yamato    6u     unix 0xf...       0t0     348924 type=STREAM pino=351122 4249,dbus-daem,55u
mozStorag 21535 22254  yamato   10u     unix 0xf...       0t0     356193 type=STREAM pino=356194 21535,gdbus,11u
mozStorag 21535 22254  yamato   11u     unix 0xf...       0t0     356194 type=STREAM pino=356193 21535,gdbus,10u
mozStorag 21535 22254  yamato   21u     unix 0xf...       0t0     355141 type=STREAM pino=357544 4249,dbus-daem,60u
mozStorag 21535 22254  yamato   26u     unix 0xf...       0t0     351134 type=STREAM pino=355142 5015,gdbus,17u
mozStorag 21535 22254  yamato   69u     unix 0xf...       0t0     469354 type=STREAM pino=468160 4545,alsa-sink,21u
mozStorag 21535 22254  yamato   82u     unix 0xf...       0t0     449383 type=STREAM pino=449384 12257,Chrome_Ch,3u
mozStorag 21535 22254  yamato   86u     unix 0xf...       0t0     355174 type=SEQPACKET pino=355175 21535,gdbus,95u
mozStorag 21535 22254  yamato   95u     unix 0xf...       0t0     355175 type=SEQPACKET pino=355174 21535,gdbus,86u 12257,Chrome_Ch,4u
mozStorag 21535 22254  yamato  100u     unix 0xf...       0t0     449389 type=STREAM pino=456453 3614,Xorg,38u
mozStorag 21535 22254  yamato  105u     unix 0xf...       0t0     582613 type=STREAM pino=586261
obexd     22163        yamato    1u     unix 0xf...       0t0     361859 type=STREAM pino=365931
obexd     22163        yamato    2u     unix 0xf...       0t0     361860 type=STREAM pino=365934
obexd     22163        yamato    3u     unix 0xf...       0t0     361241 type=DGRAM pino=10028
obexd     22163        yamato    6u     unix 0xf...       0t0     361242 type=STREAM pino=361864 4249,dbus-daem,70u
```

Answer (score 3):

Since Linux kernel 4.2 there exists `CONFIG_UNIX_DIAG`, which provides extra information about UNIX domain sockets, namely the `Virtual File System` (VFS) information, which contains the so far missing information to link the Inode from the path to the process. It can already be queried using the `ss` tool from [iproute2](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/iproute2) starting with version [v4.19.0~55](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/iproute2/iproute2.git/commit/?id=0bab7630e38863d3d2a5ddaeabf8745c4258a1a9):

```
$ ss --processes --unix --all --extended
...
Netid  State   Recv-Q  Send-Q  Local Address:Port      Peer Address:Port
u_str  LISTEN  0       5         /tmp/socket 13381347             * 0     users:(("nc",pid=12550,fd=3)) <-> ino:1569897 dev:0/65025 peers:
```

The device number and path Inode you can get from

```
$ stat -c 'ino:%i dev:0/%d' /tmp/socket
ino:1569946 dev:0/65025
```

`ss` also supports filtering:

```
 ss --processes --unix --all --extended 'sport = /tmp/socket'
```

but please be aware that this might not list the right socket for you, as an *evil* process might rename your original socket and replace it with it own evil one:

```
mv /tmp/socket /tmp/socket.orig
nc -U -l /tmp/socket.evil &
mv /tmp/socket.evil /tmp/socket
```

`lsof /tmp/socket`, `fuser /tmp/socket` and `ss --processes --unix --all --extended 'sport = /tmp/socket'` will list only the original process, **not** the evil replacement.
Instead use something like this:

```
id=$(stat -c 'ino:%i dev:0/%d' /tmp/socket)
ss --processes --unix --all --extended | grep -F "$id"
```

Or write your own little program based on the template contained in [man 7 sock_diag](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sock_diag.7.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [px](https://github.com/walles/px).

Disclaimer: I wrote it, so of course I'm recommending it.

`px` will tell you which other processes yours is talking to.

Example output, scroll to the bottom for sockets tracing:

```
~ $ sudo px 49903
/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
  --enable-audio-service-sandbox
  --origin-trial-disabled-features=MeasureMemory

kernel(0)                                     root
  launchd(1)                                  root
--> Google Chrome(49903)                      johan
      Google Chrome Helper(49922)             johan
      Google Chrome Helper(49958)             johan
      Google Chrome Helper (GPU)(49920)       johan
      Google Chrome Helper (Renderer)(49935)  johan
      Google Chrome Helper (Renderer)(49936)  johan
      Google Chrome Helper (Renderer)(49943)  johan
      Google Chrome Helper (Renderer)(49950)  johan
      Google Chrome Helper (Renderer)(49951)  johan
      Google Chrome Helper (Renderer)(49957)  johan
      Google Chrome Helper (Renderer)(64466)  johan
      Google Chrome Helper (Renderer)(75275)  johan
      Google Chrome Helper (Renderer)(76225)  johan
      Google Chrome Helper (Renderer)(76650)  johan
      Google Chrome Helper (Renderer)(76668)  johan
      Google Chrome Helper (Renderer)(76712)  johan

7d21h ago Google Chrome was started, at 2020-09-04T19:15:03+02:00.
0.3% has been its average CPU usage since then, or 32m25s/7d21h

Other processes started close to Google Chrome(49903):
  Google Chrome/chrome_crashpad_handler(49912) was started just after Google Chrome(49903)
  AlertNotificationService(49924) was started 1.0s after Google Chrome(49903)
  Google Chrome Helper(49922) was started 1.0s after Google Chrome(49903)
  Google Chrome Helper (GPU)(49920) was started 1.0s after Google Chrome(49903)
  Google Chrome Helper (Renderer)(49935) was started 1.0s after Google Chrome(49903)
  Google Chrome Helper (Renderer)(49936) was started 1.0s after Google Chrome(49903)
  VTDecoderXPCService(49934) was started 1.0s after Google Chrome(49903)

Users logged in when Google Chrome(49903) started:
  johan

2020-09-12T16:28:30.587930: Now invoking lsof, this can take over a minute on a big system...
2020-09-12T16:28:30.901834: lsof done, proceeding.

Others sharing this process' working directory (/)
  Working directory too common, never mind.

File descriptors:
  stdin : [CHR] /dev/null
  stdout: [CHR] /dev/null
  stderr: [CHR] /dev/null

Network connections:
  [IPv4] *:* (LISTEN)

Inter Process Communication:
  mDNSResponder(291): [unix] ->0x2b8028c5de1ab5b
  mDNSResponder(291): [unix] ->0x2b8028c5de1c5eb

For a list of all open files, do "sudo lsof -p 49903", or "sudo watch lsof -p 49903" for a live view.
~ $
```