# How does Bash get the output of an executed program?

Tags: bash, stdout, file-descriptors

When I execute a program in [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29), for example, `[ls][2]`, it sends its output to [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) (`fd &1`). And the ouput of the executed program is displayed in the terminal. How does Bash/terminal get the output of the `ls` command?

Comment: Are you talking about how just the output of `ls` shows up on the terminal, or how `$(ls)` allows the shell to get the output of `ls` as a string?

Comment: I'd think that those are the same processes, and since you asked they are not :), so probably the first - how the output of ls shows up on the terminal

Comment: @muru, so which answer is closer to how the output of `ls` shows up on the terminal?

Comment: I would say mine. Check the update to see if it makes things clearer.

Comment: @muru, ok, thanks! I'll read your updated answer and the stuff about `dev/pts` a little and get back to you with questions later :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a child process of the shell, `ls` inherits the open file descriptors of the shell. And the standard file descriptors (stdin, stdout, stderr (or 0, 1, 2)) are connected to a pseudo-terminal, which is handled by the terminal emulator.

For example (on a Linux system):

```
$ ls /proc/$$/fd -l
total 0
lrwx------ 1 muru muru 64 Dec 10 16:15 0 -> /dev/pts/3
lrwx------ 1 muru muru 64 Dec 10 16:15 1 -> /dev/pts/3
lrwx------ 1 muru muru 64 Dec 10 16:15 2 -> /dev/pts/3
lrwx------ 1 muru muru 64 Dec 10 16:15 255 -> /dev/pts/3
$ ls /proc/$(pgrep terminator -f)/fd -l | grep pts/3
lrwx------ 1 muru muru 64 Dec 10 16:15 26 -> /dev/pts/3
```

That is, the output of `ls`, or for that matter the shell itself, is not handled by the shell, but by the terminal emulator (GNOME Terminal, terminator, xterm, etc.).

---

You can test this out:

On Linux, find a pseudoterminal (`pts`) used by your terminal emulator (say GNOME Terminal):

```
$ ls -l /proc/$(pgrep -n gnome-terminal)/fd | grep pts
lrwx------ 1 muru muru 64 Dec 10 18:00 1 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 muru muru 64 Dec 10 18:00 15 -> /dev/pts/20
lrwx------ 1 muru muru 64 Dec 10 18:00 2 -> /dev/pts/1
```

Now, the non-standard fds (those other than 0,1,2) of `gnome-terminal` would be used by it to provide input and output for a shell. The terminal emulator reads in data send to that PTS and (after some processing, for colours and such) presents it on the screen. In this case, that would be `15`, connected to `pts/20`. If I write something to that pts, I can expect it to appear in that terminal:

[image]

Further reading:

- [What is stored in /dev/pts files and can we open them?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93531/what-is-stored-in-dev-pts-files-and-can-we-open-them)

---

The other case, where I do things like:

```
echo $(ls)
a=$(date)
vim `command -v some_script`
```

is called [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html). In command substitution, the output of the command is captured by the shell itself, and never reaches the terminal, unless you do print it out (for example, `echo $(ls)`). This case is handled in [Hauke Laging's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/172519/70524).

Comment: @HaukeLaging how much depth would be proper? An explanation of how an emulator handles the pseudoterminal?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the title (and didn't really read the question because it seemed so clear...). I thought the question was about command substitution.

Comment: @HaukeLaging It could be about command substitution, in which case you're right and this answer doesn't make sense. I'll ask OP for a clarification.

Comment: That `1 -> /dev/pts/1` in the fds of gnome-terminal point to the terminal gnome-terminal was launched from. The terminal emulators don't need access to the slave side of the pseudo terminal as they interact with it on the master side (`/dev/ptmx`). `xterm` for instance doesn't have any fd open to the slave side after it has started the  slave application (usually the shell).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I launched `gnome-terminal` from GNOME Shell's run prompt, so shouldn't it go to `/dev/null`? I tested out `xterm` and as you said it opens `/dev/ptmx`. Time for me to go and read what a master side is.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Ok, reading [`pts(4)`](http://linux.die.net/man/4/pts), the pts that `xterm` got by opening `ptmx` is only opened by the shell (and its children), right?

Comment: gnome-terminal is special because it implements a kind of client/server mechanism. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/117981 for more info on ptys.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yet I observe the same behaviour in terminator, xfce4-terminal, lxterminal and konsole. So which one is special?

Comment: I don't know about your _GNOME Shell_ software, possibly it also uses a pseudo-terminal to connect to the stdin/out/err of the applications it launches or it inherits it from the program that started it. You could try and see if it also has a fd open to /dev/ptmx or what its stdin/out/err are. See [How can we know who's at the other end of a pseudo-terminal device?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/136662)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas the GNOME Shell (and pts/1) is secondary. If I understand your comment correctly, `xterm` doesn't open the slave side it was allocated (say, `pts/20`), gnome-terminal is special because it does open the slave side. I tested out 4 other emulators, and all four open the slave side as well. So, is xterm special or are these five special?

Comment: I meant "special" in that when you run a gnome-terminal command, it just instructs a server to spawn a new window, so the extra gnome-terminal processes don't inherit the fds of the gnome-terminal command you run, but those of that server. All those terminals you mention are probably all using vte underneath which probably forgets to close that fd. I'd bet they don't do anything with that fd. xterm and rxvt (separate implementations) don't have a fd open on the slave. It doesn't make sense for the emulator to have a fd there unless they want to run a new shell when the first one's done f.i.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that I misunderstood the question in the sense of command substitution. Only in that case the shell is involved in output handling.

Hope this is of interest, too...

I attach to a shell with `strace -p 2140` before I run `echo $(/bin/echo foo)` in this thell. This is part of the result:

```
pipe([3, 4])
pipe([5, 6])
...
read(3, "foo\n", 128)
```

This is what happens in the child process:

```
dup2(4, 1)
close(4)
close(3)
...
execve("/bin/echo", ...
```

The shell connects the file descriptors 3 and 4 and then forks. The child process makes fd 4 its `stdout` before it runs the new program. Thus everything the child writes to `stdout` can be read by the parent shell on its fd 3.

Comment: Are you talking about reading the output of command substitution here?

Comment: thanks, so you answer doesn't apply to this `how the output of ls shows up on the terminal`?

Comment: @Maximus No. My answer covers the more complicated case of `$(/bin/echo foo)` instead of `echo foo`. In your simple case the shell is not involved in the output at all.

Comment: @HaukeLaging, I see, thanks. I don't understand `muru'` answer though. And if it's not involved, how come the output appears on the screen?

Comment: @Maximus The problem is probably that you don't know what a terminal / pseudo-terminal is. Have a look at Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_terminal Both the shell and the programs it runs write their output to a file descriptor – like they would write to a real file. The terminal they happen to write to makes you see their (printable) output.

Comment: Yeah, most likely this is what I need to read before trying to understand the matter. I'll do that. Thanks! Best!