# Get the terminal emulator name inside the shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script, terminal, terminal-emulator, processes

I have used `pstree` to find the name of the parent emulator of running shell script using something similar to the following:

`pstree -s $PPID | awk -F '---' '{print $6}'`

This works in my current system. I tested in `mate-terminal` and `xterm` but not sure if this will work on other Linux systems/platforms and other terminals.  Is there a better/tidier (more portable way) way of achieving this?

Comment: Related: [How can we know who's at the other end of a pseudo-terminal device?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/136662)

Comment: Do you, by "terminal", mean the terminal emulator (`xterm`, `rxvt` etc.) or the terminal device (`/dev/pts/23`, `/dev/ttyp3` etc.)?

Comment: Emulator I mean.

Comment: User: jdewolf published this code as answer to a duplicate of this question: `ps -p $(ps -h -o ppid -p $$) -o cmd`.

Comment: You really can't assume there will be a terminal emulator running a script. For example it could be an `ssh` session from a different machine, or even someone logged on to one of the non-graphic ttys.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
ps -o comm= -p "$(($(ps -o ppid= -p "$(($(ps -o sid= -p "$$")))")))"
```

May give you good results. It gives the name of the  process that is the parent of the session leader. For processes started within a terminal emulator, that would generally be the process running that terminal emulator (unless things like `screen`, `expect`, `tmux`... are being used (though note that `screen` and `tmux` *are* terminal emulators), or new sessions are started explicitly with `setsid`, `start-stop-daemon`...)

Or breaking it down into individual steps using variables (which can also help make the script more self explanatory):

```
sid=$(ps -o sid= -p "$$")
sid_as_integer=$((sid)) # strips blanks if any
session_leader_parent=$(ps -o ppid= -p "$sid_as_integer")
session_leader_parent_as_integer=$((session_leader_parent))
emulator=$(ps -o comm= -p "$session_leader_parent_as_integer")
```

The stripping of whitespace around numbers here is done using `$((...))` arithmetic expansion. You could also doing it using the split+glob operator (assuming an unmodified `$IFS`) or as suggested by @ack in comments using `xargs`:

```
ps -o sid= -p "$$" |
  xargs ps -o ppid= -p |
  xargs ps -o comm= -p
```

You could also try parsing `wtmp` where terminal emulators usually log an entry with their pid associated with the pseudo-terminal device. This works for me on a Debian system provided expect/screen/tmux... are not involved:

```
ps -o comm= -p "$(
  dump-utmp -r /var/log/wtmp |
  awk -v tty="$(ps -o tty= -p "$$")" -F ' *\\| *' '
    $2 == tty {print $5;exit}')"
```

(using `dump-utmp` from GNU `acct`).

Comment: While the first implementation looks kinda Lispy (and don't get me wrong, I like Lisp a lot!) and the second expanded one looks more like Lisp doing Warp 9, Bash isn't such a great Lisp. The other implementations are IMHO much more complicated than they need to be. There is a much simpler, straightforward, down to Earth way of doing it, using just plain old pipes: `$ ps -o sid= -p "$$" | xargs ps -o ppid= -p | xargs ps -o comm= -p`

Comment: @ack, very good point, I've added it in.

Answer (score 2):

To find the name of the terminal emulator used by the current shell, you could ask the X window system to give you the name of the window that the shell is currently visible in:

```
$ xwininfo -id $WINDOWID | awk '/^xwin/ { print $NF }'
```

This gives back the string `"xterm"` for me in XTerm, and `"urxvt"` when I run in Rxvt-unicode. The result will probably be different if you have the habit of changing the window title though, because that's what is being handed back to you here I think.

Comment: What if `xwininfo` is not available?

Comment: Well, what if `pstree` is not available or if it's incompatible with your original solution? (The `-s` flag on OpenBSD systems, for example, have different semantics).

Comment: That is exactly the reason I was looking for something more portable!

Comment: That gives you the window's title which can be overridden at run time or in configuration, you could use `eval "$(xprop -notype -id "$WINDOWID" 32i '=$0' _NET_WM_PID)"; ps -o comm= -p "$_NET_WM_PID"` to get the process name instead.

Comment: @cofferMug, `xwininfo` is a standard X command like `xprop`. If your system has X11 terminal emulators, it should have those commands.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I run the script on a `Gentoo` based system and I have `xterm`, `xclock` and so on but no `xwininfo`! Maybe the system is a customized one.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas `ps -o comm= ...` would cut long process name (gnome-terminal-server => gnome-terminal-). An alternative way, `xprop -id $WINDOWID WM_CLASS | cut -d'"' -f2`, if instance in WM_CLASS (the first string) was set correctly.

Comment: @zhazha, strictly speaking, `ps -o comm=` does give you the full process name, it's just that the process name on Linux is limited to 15 bytes.

Comment: Not all terminal emulators define $WINDOWID

Comment: @pmav99 Sure, and not all scripts run within a terminal emulator either.

Answer (score 1):

Building on [stephane-chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%C3%A9phane-chazelas) solution to make it work under tmux (i.e. return the terminal emulator that the tmux client is using for display), this seems to work for me:

```
TERMINAL_EMULATOR="$(ps --pid $(ps --pid $$ -o ppid=) -o comm=)"
if [[ "${TERMINAL_EMULATOR}" =~ tmux ]]; then
    export TERMINAL_EMULATOR=$(ps --pid "$(($(ps --pid $(ps --pid $(tmux display-message -p "#{client_pid}") -o sid=) -o ppid=)))" -o comm=)
else
    export TERMINAL_EMULATOR
fi
```