# Preserving environment variables (custom shell prompts) in nnn subshells

Tags: shell, zsh, nnn

I run two different terminal emulators with different `zsh` prompts depending on whether I am in one or the other (with the second being the "default"):

```bash
TERM_EMU=$(ps --pid $(ps --pid $$ -o ppid=) -o comm=)
if [ $TERM_EMU = 'term1' ]; then
    PS1='term1> '
else
    PS1='term2> '
fi
```

(Where I have taken the terminal emulator name finding command from [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264329/get-the-terminal-emulator-name-inside-the-shell-script))

However, I also use `nnn` for file navigation and frequently spawn its subshells. Whenever I enter an `nnn` subshell, the process id of the terminal emulator found with the `ps` command becomes `nnn`, and the shell switches to the "default" prompt. I want to sync the subshell prompts with my main prompt setting.

My first idea was to check if I'm at zero subshell depth first; this would presumably set my shell prompt to a variable that would later be referenced by the subshells:

```bash
if [ -z $NNNLVL ]; then
    TERM_EMU=$(ps --pid $(ps --pid $$ -o ppid=) -o comm=)
    if [ $TERM_EMU = 'term1' ]; then
        PS1='term1> '
    else
        PS1='term2> '
    fi
else
    PS1="($NNNLVL) $PS1"
fi
```

This doesn't work; instead, the subshell prompt becomes

```
(<level>) <hostname>%
```

which is not at all what I want; apparently the `PS1` variable is not carried over to the subshells. How do I force `nnn` shells to "remember" their parent terminal emulator?

Comment: Can't you just use `$TERM`? Note that the parent process of the one that executed your shell is already in `$PPID`. It's more the parent process of your session leader that you'd want here `$(ps -o ppid= -p $(ps -o sid= -p $$))`

Comment: "Can't you just use `$TERM`?" - No, most terminal emulators share that variable. In fact this is just a working example, in my actual script I also customize `TERM` for a specific terminal emulator to achieve the effects I want.

Comment: Also, the command you provided just gives me an error: `zsh: command not found: 330219` I don't really know how `ps` works and can't debug that...

Comment: Yes, that's the point terminal emulators set `$TERM` to a value that tells applications what the terminal is so they know how to interact with it. That `$(ps -o pid=....)`  was meant to be the pid of the parent of the session leader, not a command to run.