# delete lines that sum to zero

Tags: text-processing

I need to delete all lines in a file, if the values in all the columns are 0 (so if the sum of the row is 0).

My file is like this (13 columns and 60000 rows, tab delimited)

```
KO  gene    S10 S11 S12 S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  S6  S7  S8  S9
K02946  aap:NT05HA_2163 0   0   0   0   1   0   8   0   0   5   0   0
K06215  aar:Acear_1499  0   0   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0
K00059  acd:AOLE_11635  0   0   5   0   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0
K00991  afn:Acfer_0744  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
K01784  aha:AHA_2893    0   0   0   0   0   0   7   0   0   0   0   0
K01497  amd:AMED_3340   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

How can I do?

Comment: `grep -v '0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0$'` (tabs in between).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: You mean `grep -v`?

Comment: @Costas, ITYM `grep -vE '( 0){12}$'` (TAB before `0`)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes, your solution is cool, it looks great. (sorry I forgot brackets and have wrong counting of zeros: there are 11 only)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd like `awk` solution:

```
awk '{s=0; for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) s+=$i; if (s!=0)print}' infile > outfile
```

If you like to remain first line as header start script from the second:

```
awk 'NR > 1{s=0; for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) s+=$i; if (s!=0)print}' infile > outfile
```

Answer (score 3):

If your columns contain only non-negative number, you only have to print line have at least one field with number greater than 0.

With `perl`:

```
$ perl -MList::Util=first -anle '
  print if first {$_ > 0} @F or $. == 1;
' file
KO  gene    S10 S11 S12 S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  S6  S7  S8  S9
K02946  aap:NT05HA_2163 0   0   0   0   1   0   8   0   0   5   0   0
K06215  aar:Acear_1499  0   0   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0
K00059  acd:AOLE_11635  0   0   5   0   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0
K01784  aha:AHA_2893    0   0   0   0   0   0   7   0   0   0   0   0
```

You should read [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170013/security-implications-of-running-perl-ne) for security reason if using `perl` solution.

With `awk`:

```
$ awk 'FNR == 1{print;next}{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) if($i > 0){print;next}}' file
```

Comment: This is a pretty good insight, I think. I think it would work with `grep` like: `grep '\t[1-9]'`. It's probably better to use a literal tab there, but it's much harder to represent in a comment.