# Delete columns that sum to zero

Tags: text-processing, awk, columns, table

I have a numeric table, that is all cells have numbers. It is a tab-delimited file, with non-numeric headers and row names. I need to delete all columns that add up zero. I would like to keep the first column (row names), and the headers of the rest of the columns that were not removed.

Input

```
a  b  c  d
e  1  2  0
f  3  4  0
g  5  6  0
```

Output

```
a  b  c
e  1  2
f  3  4
g  5  6
```

Analogous problem but with rows: [delete lines that sum to zero](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170588/delete-lines-that-sum-to-zero)

**awk** solution would be awesome; I want to avoid loading huge files in R.

Comment: give us a sample input/output example as well as what you've tried so far...

Comment: Are the values in your file always integers ?

Comment: Values are always integers.

Comment: You said 'keep headers' but 'd' disappeared ...

Answer (score 2):

to remove **column**

c.awk :

```
 { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { line[NR][i]=$i ; col[i]+=$i ;} }
END {
 for ( l=1 ; l<=NR ; l++ )
  {
    printf line[l][1]   "\t" ;
    for (c=2;c<=NF;c++) if (col[c]) printf line[l][c]  "\t" ;
    printf "\n" ;
  }
}
```

where

- `{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { line[NR][i]=$i ; col[i]+=$i ;} }` store all line (including col names).
- `END` clause print all column if count != 0 .
- beware that all data are kept in memory.

test:

```
awk -f c.awk a
a   b       c
e   1       2
f   3       4
g   5       6
```

for line solution ...

try

```
 awk 'NR==1 {print } NR>1 { s=0 ; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) s+=$i ; if (s) print ;}'
```

where

- `NR==1 {print }` print header
- `NR>1 { s=0 ; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) s+=$i ; if (s) print ;}` test for 0 and print if not
- you may start with `i=2` if first column is row name.
- beware of floating point numbers, they may not sum up to 0.

note this will output lines, not delete from original file.

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier with `perl` if you want to keep the spacing:

```
perl -lne '
   $i = 0;
   for (/\S+\s*/g) {
      $cell[$.][$i] = $_;
      $sum[$i++] += $_
   }
   END{
     @keep=(0, grep {$sum[$_]} (1..$#sum));
     print((@{$cell[$_]})[@keep]) for (1..$.)
   }'
```

That loads the whole file in memory. To avoid that, you'd need two passes in the file.

That could be done with a combination of `awk` and `sed`:

```
awk '
  NR>1{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) sum[i]+=$i; if (NF>n) n = NF}
  END {
    for (;n>1;n--)
      if (!sum[n])
        print "s/[^[:blank:]]\\{1,\\}[[:blank:]]*//" n
  }' < file | sed -f - file
```

`awk` generating the `sed` script to remove the columns whose sum is 0. The `s/[^[:blank:]]\{1,\}[[:blank:]]*//3` `sed` commands would remove the columns while preserving the spacing of the other columns, but would be quite expensive, you may want to do that stripping in `perl` if performance is an issue.

For rows, it's a lot easier:

```
perl -MList::Util=sum -lane 'print if $. == 1 or sum @F'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since those values are always integers you could do something like:

```
cut $(awk 'NR>1{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) s[i]+=$i}END{printf("%s", "-f 1");
for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {if (s[i]) printf(",%s", i)}}' infile) infile
```

this reads the file twice: `awk` gets the column numbers where the sum isn't zero; these are then used with `cut` to print only the desired columns.