# Dynamically reference a file's name

Tags: shell, files, filenames

In a single directory, I'd like to replace the first line of each file with the file's name. Each file has as the first line "TestRelation." I'd like to replace it with the file's name.

I know I can use `perl -pi -w -e 's/SEARCH_FOR/REPLACE_WITH/g;' *.txt` to go through all of the files. But how do I dynamically change the "REPLACE_WITH" with the file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
perl -i.bak -wpe 's/SEARCH_FOR/$ARGV/g' *.txt
```

[$ARGV](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24ARGV) contain the name of current file when reading from `<>`.

Because you using `-i` switch, you don't have to worry about [security implication](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/170013/38906) when running `perl` with `-n` or `-p` switch.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. And for anyone wondering, you can use `find . -name "*.bak" -delete` to delete all of the `.bak` files.

Answer (score 1):

A shell script with a "here document" will handle this nicely:

```
#!/bin/bash
for NAME in t?
do
ex -s $NAME << END_EDITS
1s/TestRelation/$NAME/
w!
q
END_EDITS
done
```

Not knowing what your files are named, I chose "t1", "t2", "t3", etc as file names. You will have to generate file names as appropriate.

The "for" loop gives shell variable `NAME` the value of a file's name each time through the loop. The `bash` instance executing the above script calls the `ex` editor on each file name, and gives it some input lines. The `1s/TestRelation/$NAME/` ex command gets expanded by the `bash` instance, which substitutes a file's name for the "$NAME" part.

You have to have the token that ends the "here document" (`END_EDITS` in this case) at the beginning of a line, no white space in front.

Answer (score 0):

If you just wish to do it in shell, use `find` command to list files and then `basename` command to get the file name and use `sed` to replace the string

```
for i  in $(find . -type f); do fname=$(basename $i); sed -i "s/TestRelation/${fname}/" $fname; done
```

Well `basename` and `find` is not required and you can just use `ls` if you are sure of only files in a particular dir you are searching

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Could you expand on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

`` for i in `ls *.sh`; do echo "$i">>$i.new; cat $i.new $i >>$i.new;done ``

What this does it basically list the files and store the filenames. Write those names to a new file and cat it with the original file. You can also move the .new file to the original filename if required. This is not the most elegant option, but it works.