# Using Perl to modify specified lines of an ASCII file

Tags: text-processing, perl

**Background:**

(1) I have a data set of scientific notation:

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.503832e-05, 1.433673e-05, 2.557402e-05, 
    3.081098e-05, 4.044465e-05, 2.480817e-05, 2.681778e-05, 1.533265e-05, 
    2.3156e-05, 3.193812e-05, 5.325314e-05, 1.639066e-05, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.259782e-05, 0.0004197799, 2.65868e-05, 0.0002485498, 
    3.485129e-05, 2.454055e-05, 0.0002096856, 0.0001910835, 1.969936e-05, 
    2.974743e-05, 8.983165e-05, 0.0004263787, 0.0004444561, 0.000241368, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

(2) I aim to add a certain values to those non-zero values.

(3) Thanks to the warm help from other stack-exchange users, I got a solution by using:

```
perl -pe 's/([0-9.e-]+)/$1 == 0 ? $1 : .001 + $1/ge' < input.txt > output.txt
```

---

**My Problem:**

I have two following-up questions:

(Q1) I know that from `sed`, we can, says, extract few lines from an input file and save those lines to an output file by:

```
sed -n (123,345p) input.txt > output.txt
```

Which extracted lines 123 to Line 345 from `input.txt` and saved to `ouput.txt`.

However, I do not have ideas how I can modify the above `perl` script to add numbers to the specified lines of the ascii file.

(Q2) Can I add an `option` to the above `perl` script such that my changes are directly added to the input.txt file? I have tried to modify `-pe` as `-pei` but it seems does not work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/([0-9.e-]+)/$1 == 0 ? $1 : .001 + $1/ge if 123..345' input.txt
```

- `-i.bak` make `perl` edit file in-place and make a backup file `input.txt.bak` (I invite you to read [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/170013/38906))
- `if 123..345` using flip-flop operator, emulate line-range operator of `sed`, `awk`.