# Replacing a character at a random position using sed?

Tags: sed

I'm trying to replace a character in a file at a random position.  My file looks something like:

```
aab  
babab  
abab
```

I'm trying to replace a random character for 'c'.  So the output might look like:

```
aab  
bcbab  
abab
```

I have tried removing all line breaks and saving in a file new_string.txt and then using sed but it isn't working.

This is the code I have tried:

```
rand1="$(shuf -i 0-$tot_len -n 1)"
sed "s/^\(.\{"${rand1}"\}\)./\1G/" new_string.txt
```

I keep getting the error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 25: Invalid content of \{\}
```

Comment: A _random character_? Or _a random character other than newline_?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas he meant a character at a random position in the string.

Comment: A random character apart from the newline.

Comment: A random character **or** a character at random position **or** a random character at random position?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.  A specified character at a random position

Comment: Your problem may very well be in your `$rand1` or `$tot_len` variable. Run that with `set -x` and quote your variables. The sed error  mentions `char 25` but that expression has fewer than 25 characters.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas if you read @Fiximan answer you'll see that my value of `$rand1` is too large for sed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for the curly brackets in your variable, and the variable should be quoted as well. Use:

```
sed "s/^\(.\{$rand1\}\)./\1G/" new_string.txt
```

---

UPDATE: as stated below in comments:

The original code is fine, however the integer for `$rand1` is too large for `sed`. I found that the maximum value can be `32767` for GNU `sed`, i.e. `sed` still takes 16bit integers only.

You can obtain that limit for the system's regular expression library (though GNU `sed` generally uses a builtin version) with:

```
$ getconf RE_DUP_MAX
32767
```

POSIX requires that limit to be at least `_POSIX_RE_DUP_MAX` (255), and that's the maximum you can expect portably (some systems like Solaris or OS/X have it as low as that).

Comment: I've tried that too.  I still get the same error.

Comment: what is `echo $rand1` giving you? because it worked in my test.

Comment: echo $rand1 works fine

Comment: what is the output of `echo $rand1 | cat -A` ?

Comment: 5255810$ . 5255810 is the value of $rand1 and my string is larger than that

Comment: seems to be a limitation of `sed`: `rand1=10000` works fine at my machine, `rand1=100000` doesn't (with same as your error). Maybe get a workaround by a) selecting a random line, b) selecting a random position in that line

Comment: btw: it breaks down after: `rand1=32767`, or in other words: the highest 16bit integer

Comment: Sadly I need them to be picked with uniform probability and since all my lines are different lengths I can't do that.

Comment: Is the total number of characters random? You could `fold` your single line into equal sized lines and then do two random picks (line and character). Would be uniform if all lines are of same length after `fold`ing.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I will use `fold` but then since the last line may not be the same length I will instead use `$rand1` modulo linelength to get position in line and the floor of `$rand1` to get line number.  Then I'll use sed as above.

Comment: Note that it depends on the `sed` implementation. On Solaris 10 x86_64, for both /usr/xpg4/bin/sed and /bin/sed, and on Apple OS/X the limit is 255 (the minimum required by POSIX (_POSIX_RE_DUP_MAX)).

Answer (score 1):

On a GNU system, to substitute one character (other than newline) at random, you could do:

```
file=myfile.txt
offset=$(grep -bo . < "$file" | cut -d: -f1 | shuf -n1)
[ -z "$offset" ] || # file doesn't have non-newline characters
  printf c | dd bs=1 seek="$offset" of="$file" conv=notrunc status=none
```

(with old versions of GNU `dd` (prior to 8.20), replace `status=none` with `2> /dev/null`).

`grep -bo . < "$file"` would give you the offset in number of bytes in the file of each non-newline character. For instance, with a file encoded in UTF-8 that contains:

```
$3
£1
€2
```

That gives us:

```
$ grep -bo . < "$file"
0:$
1:3
3:£
5:1
7:€
10:2
```

With `cut -d: -f1`, we retain the part before the first colon. Then, we pick one of those offsets at random with `shuf -n1`.

That assumes the replacement  character has the same size as the replaced one. For instance, replacing that £ above (2 bytes) with c (1 byte) would leave the file with `c` followed by an invalid character.

To work around that, we can't overwrite the file in-place anymore as we'd need to shift data around.

We'd need something like:

```
perl -C -0777 -pi -e "substr \$_, $offset, 1, 'c'" -- "$file"
```

instead. With `-C`, `perl` honours the locale for what constitutes a *character*. `-0777 -p` turns on the *slurp* mode where the content of `$file` is slurped into `$_` (see [Security implications of running perl -ne '…' *](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/170013) though for security considerations with that construct). `-pi` gives you in-place editing, `$_` is written back to the file after the code is run. Then we call `substr` to substitute the 1 character at the given offset with `c`.

Comment: I've just blindly copied your code as I don't quite understand what you've done but I have the error message: dd: invalid status flag: ‘none’

Comment: @user3891532, see edit, you must have an old version of GNU dd.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed 's/^\(.\{'"${rand1}"'\}\)./\1G/'  new_string.txt
```

Comment: That doesn't work either

Comment: are you still geting same error??

Comment: It's still the same error.

Comment: What is value in tot_len?? Is it getting some value or it os blank??

Comment: may be rand1 value is getting some value larger than the string length.

Comment: If you read Fiximan's answer you'll see that my value of `$rand1` was too large for sed to handle.

Answer (score 0):

With new GNU sed you can do it even without `\n`ewline remove

```
sed -z "s/./@/$(($RANDOM%$(wc -m < file.txt)))" file.txt
```

Comment: Note that $RANDOM is ksh/zsh/bash specific and is limited to 0-32767.

Comment: That assumes `file.txt` doesn't contain NUL characters (which should be a safe assumption for a text file, just as that it contains only valid characters in the current locale which is also a requirement (and of my answer as well)).

Comment: Note that it may replace newline characters.