# How to safely use gawk's -i option or @include directive?

Tags: awk, security

Using `gawk -i inplace some-awk-code some-file` (or `@include "inplace"` within an `awk` script) to edit a file in-place (or any other extension) [is a security vulnerability](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2023-06/msg00027.html).

Why?

How do I work around it?

Comment: I've just edited most of [my answers that were using `-i inplace`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A22565+inplace) after realising how broken that was, I'm posting this Q&A here to explain why.

Comment: I just VTC’ed [a question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/754710/80216) as a duplicate of [How to change a file in-place using awk? (as with "sed -i")](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/496179/80216), because it was the best canonical Q/A I could find.  You might want to edit [the accepted answer there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496187/80216) (by Kusalananda) or at least comment on it.

Answer (score 27):

GNU `awk` has a few extensions over the standard when it comes to specifying the code to run.

While in standard `awk`, you can only pass the code either as one or more `-f filepath` where `filepath` is taken as the path of a file where to read the code from¹ or as the first non-option argument (as in `awk -- 'literal code here'`), gawk has a few more options:

- `-e 'literal code'` (or `--source 'literal code'`) like in `sed`, you can split the code into more than one argument which you can intersperse with `-f filepath` ones.
- `-E filepath` (or `--exec filepath`), same as `-f` except there can be only one, and whatever follows it not considered for options or variable assignments, only file paths (or `-` for stdin).
- `--file filepath`: alias for `-f`.
- `-i filepath` (or `--include filepath`): similar to `-f` but with some variations in behaviours [as noted in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Options.html#index-_002di-option).

Now, the problem is that in `gawk`, *filepath* in all of the above is not always treated as a file path:

1. if *filepath* doesn't exist, `gawk` will try to open the same file with a `.awk` extension added. That means it may end up interpreting code you didn't intend it to, but that's unlikely to be a problem in practice as the file you intended it to run has not to exist for that to happen. It doesn't do that with `--traditional` or `-W traditional`, but then you can't use most of gawk's extensions with that.
2. if *filepath* does not contain `/` characters (and is not `-`), then the awk program is looked up in a `$AWKPATH` environment variable in a similar way as shells or `execvp()` look-up slash-less commands in `$PATH`, and that's including with `--posix` and with `--traditional`, for all of `-f`/`-i`/`-E` (and both without and with a `.awk` extension added as per above).

The second point is at the core of the problem here.

You can find out what the default AWKPATH is with:

```
$ (unset -v AWKPATH && gawk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["AWKPATH"]}')
.:/usr/share/awk
```

(even though there's no such variable in the `ENVIRON`ment!)

It starts with `.`, the current working directory, followed by a system location that contains a few extensions shipped with `awk` or other third party modules for `gawk`. On this system:

```
$ ls /usr/share/awk
assert.awk      getlong.awk    intdiv0.awk    ord.awk           rewind.awk
bits2str.awk    getopt.awk     isnumeric.awk  passwd.awk        round.awk
cliff_rand.awk  gettime.awk    join.awk       processarray.awk  shellquote.awk
ctime.awk       group.awk      libintl.awk    quicksort.awk     strtonum.awk
dpkg-awk.awk    have_mpfr.awk  noassign.awk   readable.awk      walkarray.awk
ftrans.awk      inplace.awk    ns_passwd.awk  readfile.awk      zerofile.awk
```

That means that for `-f`/`-E`, if you want the `file` in the current working directory to be loaded, you need `gawk -f ./file`, not `gawk -f file` which could load a `file` (or `file.awk`) from somewhere else if there was no `file` in the current working directory. Like you need `./cmd` in shells to run the `cmd` in the current working directory (except that `$PATH` for safety reasons usually doesn't contain `.`, and that `gawk` will try to load `file.awk` as seen above).

That also applies for `-i`, except one usually uses `-i` to *include* gawk extensions from a library  in which case you *do* want those to be looked-up in the directories where they're meant to be found and you *do* want the `.awk` extension to be added (as those library extensions usually have such an extension).

In `gawk -i inplace 'some code' some-file`, you do want `gawk` to find `/usr/share/awk/inplace.awk` (or wherever `inplace.awk` is installed on your system), but the problem here is that the default AWKPATH *starts* with `.`, so `gawk` will first look for it in `./inplace` and `./inplace.awk`.

If you run that in `/tmp` or any directory that is writeable or has been writeable by others or generally cannot be trusted, you may end up running malicious code.

For instance, run:

```
echo 'BEGIN{system("reboot")}' > /tmp/inplace
```

And you'll find that any script that does `awk -i inplace` whilst their current working directory is `/tmp` reboots the system!

To work around that:

- Either hardcode the path of the `inplace` extension by using `awk -i /usr/share/awk/inplace.awk` instead of <strike>`awk -i inplace`</strike>, though you may need to adapt the path to every system or gawk deployment.
- or remove `.` and all relative path components from `$AWKPATH`:

  ```sh
  export AWKPATH="$(LC_ALL=C gawk 'BEGIN {
    n = split(ENVIRON["AWKPATH"], dirs, ":")
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
      if (substr(dirs[i], 1, 1) == "/") {
        newawkpath = newawkpath sep dirs[i]
        sep = ":"
      }
    if (newawkpath == "") newawkpath = "/dev/null"
    print newawkpath}')"
  ```

  Bearing in mind that you will need to use `gawk -f ./file` or `awk -E ./file` to load the file in the current working directory (which you should probably do already even without that change to `$AWKPATH` as seen above). Also note that versions of gawk prior to 4.1.2 looked into the current working directory after looking in `$AWKPATH`.

  That approach can't be used in a `#! /usr/bin/gawk -E` script that uses `@include` though since the `$AWKPATH` must already be in the environment by the time `gawk` is started. So if you have a `gawk` script that uses `@include "some-extension"` you need to tell your users to change their `$AWKPATH` or hard code the path of the extension as per above.
- or use `perl` which has had a `-i` option for inplace-editing for decades and can do anything `awk` can do and much more in a much saner syntax² and fewer portability issues. But don't forget the `--` in `perl -i -ne 'perl code' -- *.txt` or you'd introduce code injection vulnerabilities as well (or use `./*.txt`; see [Security implications of running perl -ne '...' *](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/170013))!

---

<sup>¹ except when that *filepath* is `-` in which case most `awk` implementations interpret it as meaning the code is to be read from standard input.</sup>

<sup>² `perl`'s `-M` option, which could be seen as an equivalent of `gawk`'s `-i` looks the `M`odules up in `$PERL5LIB` or `$PERLLIB`, with a default search path (see `(unset -v PERL5LIB PERLLIB && perl -le 'print for @INC'`) that doesn't include `.` nor any other relative path</sup>

Comment: @EdMorton, that was my original intention prior to post this and fix my answers, but the behaviour here is clearly as designed and documented. The goals of `-f` (run a script) and `-i` (load a module) are clearly hard to reconcile without breaking one or the other. Maybe a new `-I` that doesn't look in the current directory could be an option. It looks like that's another poor API we'll have to live with and navigate around until a better one is introduced. But feel free to bring it up to Arnold, he may have some better idea on how to improve it. For my part, I think I'll just give up on awk.

Comment: @EdMorton the whole thing is a bit half baked. See that AWKPATH that gawk pretends is in ENVIRON when it's not really (having a `PROCINFO["awkpath"]` initialised from an AWKPATH variable might have been a better API). The `@include`'s that can't be done at run time. Those functions added to `/etc/profile.d` where that doesn't make much sense as profile.d is for the session initialisation, only  read by login shells...

Comment: Or pipe commands to ed for very simple tasks

Comment: @EdMorton, it's not specific to `inplace`, that applies to any extension like `gawk -i shellquote` etc. It's just `inplace` is the most widely used, and the only one I've ever used myself. Thanks for the link to that  discussion though.

Comment: @EdMorton, [I've now raised it on the bug-gawk mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2023-06/msg00027.html).

Comment: @EdMorton Arnold came back with a kind of expected although disappointing reply, so all we can do now is raise awareness to that misdesign. [a github code search for "-i inplace"](https://github.com/search?q=%22-i+inplace%22&type=code&p=2) returns 1.4k entries many of which will be security vulnerabilities, and that's only counting inclusions of the `inplace` extension. Many Q&As here use -i inplace, I've only "fixed" mine, and started posting some warning comments on some others.

Comment: I saw Arnold's response as I'm on that mailing list. That's too bad but, as you say, not entirely unexpected. I wonder how many non-inplace `gawk -i`s are out there... Anyway, thanks for raising awareness and following up with the providers, can't ask for more than that!

Comment: *"I wonder how many non-inplace gawk -is are out there"*. Not much returned by a github search. I see some `assert`, `readfile`, `join` being used and a few custom ones, but nowhere as common as `-i inplace`.

Answer (score 13):

First off, kudos @StephaneChazelas for saying what I keep saying for years now in every forum i write: hands off of `sed -i` and `awk -i inplace`!

In addition to what you already said (and which is in parts new to me, this is even more broken than I thought it is):

1. "-in-place"? Not really!

   `sed -i` and `awk -i inplace` both pretend to edit "inplace", but they don't. In fact they create a (hidden) temporary file as output and move that at last, overwriting the original. Basically the same what one does using POSIX-confirming variants, but automatically so. This sounds like a good idea, but from "in-place" i would expect the inode-number and the ownership and filemode to be retained. **This is not the case!** In fact all three properties are changed given the right prerequisites (i.e. a user allowed to write the file but with a different primary group than the file has, directories with sticky bits, ...).

   Now, don't get me wrong: there is no problem with that happening and it would happen the same way if my process were to write to a temporary file and then do the copying itself. But in this case I'd be *aware of it* and would make sure the file mode, etc.. is corrected after the change. Since this pretends to work *in-place* chances are users are not aware of this effect.
2. The non-existing temporary file

   The next problem is: if modifying a file and creating a temporary file in the process I will take precautions: there must be enough space to hold the temporary file, I will make sure to remove the temporary file afterwards, etc.. Since I don't know where the temporary file goes (there is nothing about it in the man page, purportedly all happens "in-place") I have no control over it and in case the system crashes mid-script (these things happen) I have no idea I even left some artefact around to eat up disk space.

Comment: It's true that perl/sed's `-i` or `gawk`'s `inplace.awk` don't modify the file in place, break hardlinks and symlinks and may lose some meta data, but there's no perfect solution here. The alternative approaches that keep the original files have issues of their own, like the risk of having a file half processed, it not being atomical, and changing a file while it's being used by another process can have nasty side effects. All is all the `perl -i` approach (that GNU `sed` or `awk` emulate) is one of the least bad ones and probably the best as a generic one.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: the problem is NOT the automatic replacement of the file to change. I agree, this *would* be a nifty idea, but: don't call it "in-place" then! Call it "automatic-replacement" or whatever. Do, whatever you want, but don't lie to your user! (side remark: This is exactly what is wrong with M$$ products - if they tell you they do "A" chances are they in fact do "B", because they think it is better for you than the "C" you asked for. ) And, first and foremost: DOCUMENT IT! Why is no mention of this in the man pages? Why do I have to use "truss" to debug my tools?

Comment: that `-i`nplace comes from perl in the 80s and the behaviour is clearly documented there (GNU and FreeBSD seds added something similar only decades later and GNU awk again much later still). See `perldoc perlrun`. It's still "in place" in that the editing result ends up in a file with the same name. Maybe not the best word, but I for one can't think of a better one.

Comment: An in-place, atomic edit of a file is supposed to be achieved by OS support, via a feature sometimes called "atomic supersede".  The trade-offs you see are due to having to simulate that in user space. If you are to have atomicity, you cannot write into the same file. If you don't write into the same file, you don't have .. the same file.

Comment: If you want a real in-place edit (i.e. one that preserves the inode number, permissions, owner, and group), use `ed` or `ex` or similar OR, instead of doing something like `mv tmpfile original_file` (which is typically what `-i` / `--in-place` options do on most programs that have the option) you need to do the equivalent of `cat tmpfile > original_file ; rm tmpfile`.

Comment: @cas: you are right. My problem isn't, though, that -i/--in-place *works* like it does, my problem is that it *pretends* to do something but in fact does something else. That was the whole point of my post. Basically: don't lie to the user!

Comment: yes, that's all true but 1. the behaviour was documented accurately in perl, where `-i` originated 2. in most cases, the behaviour is "good enough" because the inode number doesn't matter and the owner/groups/perms don't matter because the user is working with their own files in their own directories, with the same `umask` they normally use. 3. for those instances where this does matter, there are well-known methods (e.g. edit in ram, overwrite the original or write to tmpfile, overwrite original, delete tmpfile).

Comment: 4. I agree that it's a good idea to point out the inode/owner/group/perms issues (i.e. everything that can come from creating a new file and replacing the original) with `-i` in answers recommending it....but they're not a reason to never use or recommend `-i`.   5. back to the documentation issue - lots of things have less than perfect documentation, or gloss over the details.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally, gawk has an AWKLIBPATH variable for which there is a default value if it's not found in the environment. This variable governs where `@load "library"` will look up library files:
[Loading Shared Libraries](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Loading-Shared-Libraries.html)

The default value appears not to use `.` directory (for the version I have installed), but I suppose that could change.

Comment: Yes, AWKLIBPATH seems to be fine in that regard.

Answer (score 2):

As far as `@include` goes, there is my [`cppawk`](https://kylheku.com/cgit/cppawk/about). It is a small shell script wrapper for awk which lets you use the C preprocessor, with its `#include` and macros and all.

`#include` doesn't look in the current directory. It does something better: when the header name is in double quotes, it looks for it in the same directory as the file in which the `#include` directive is found.
This makes it easy to make a `cppawk` program out of multiple files: the main file easily finds its other files using relative paths in `#include "..."` directives.

`cppawk` has a few library headers of its own, but none provide a solution for in-place file editing. The utility would make it easy to reuse a solution.

Here is a low quality prototype:

```
$ cat file.bak
alpha
bravo
charlie
$ cp file.bak file
$ cppawk '
#include "inplace.h"
{ out(NR, $0) }
' file
$ cat file
1 alpha
2 bravo
3 charlie
```

Contents of `inplace.h`:

```
BEGIN {
  __inplace_tmpfile = "xyz.tmp"
  __inplace_origfile = ARGV[1]
}

END {
  close(__inplace_tmpfile)
  system("mv " __inplace_tmpfile " " __inplace_origfile)
}

#define out(...) print __VA_ARGS__ >  __inplace_tmpfile
```

Here we need at least the following: a better way to obtain the temporary file, and also to shell-escape the content of `ARGV[1]` so that we can safely interpolate it into the `mv` command.

We could have a default implementation of `out` somewhere which doesn't have the redirection. We then make a habit of using that instead of `print` in `cppawk` programs so that when `inplace.h` is included, code doesn't have to be modified.

We can achieve some of this without preprocessing, since `-f` can be used to include script material. Instead of an `inplace.h` header, we prepare an `inplace.awk` file which has this:

```
BEGIN {
  inplace = "xyz.tmp"
  __inplace_origfile = ARGV[1]
}

END {
  close(inplace)
  system("mv " inplace " " __inplace_origfile)
}
```

We have de-anonymized the name of the variable that holds the temp file; it's part of the interface now.

Unfortunately to be able to  mix `-f` inclusion with in-command-line script material, we need the GNU-specific `-e` option:

```
$ mv file.bak file
$ awk -f inplace.awk -e '{ print NR, $0 > inplace }' file
$ cat file
1 alpha
2 bravo
3 charlie
```

There is also the question of how to refer to `inplace.awk`. Where do we put it and how do we find it? `#include` doesn't have that problem. If we ship it with the code, it will find it next to itself. If we stick it into `cppawk` as a library header it will be `<inplace.h>`; again, no problem. We also have the option of using `cppawk --prepro-only` to capture the entire "translation unit", which can then be run without requiring the `cpp` preprocessor.

Comment: This has made me realize that a shell escaping function is essential in the Awk toolkit; cppawk should provide that. Any time you use system() with paths, you have a potential injection problem.

Comment: `system("mv " __inplace_tmpfile " " __inplace_origfile)` should be `system("mv -- \047" __inplace_tmpfile "\047 \047" __inplace_origfile "\047")` or similar so the file names are quoted rather than being exposed to the shell for interpretation (and the `--` so it can handle file names that start with `-`, which may not be possible in your code, idk).

Comment: You'd obviously also need to handle the cases of multiple file names and/or the file name being stored in ARGV[2] or some other location, e.g. to handle something like `awk '{print FNR, $0}' OFS=":" file1 OFS=";" file2`.