# Is it safe to redirect output of the awk command to the same file used for input?

Tags: shell, awk, io-redirection

In this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660079/how-to-save-the-output-of-this-awk-command-to-file#comment98634097_14660111), community member DannyDannyDanny asked if it is safe to redirect output of the `awk` command to the same file being used for input.

No one answered that comment, so I would like to formally ask that question here.

Specifically, my intent is to use this `awk` command:

```
awk '!($0 in a) {if (NF) a[$0]; print}' filename > filename
```

Please note that `filename` = `filename`.

Comment: Use `sponge`, a tool from `GNU` `more-utils`: `awk ... file | sponge file`

Comment: Also while GNU awk can do it `inplace`, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/749646/70524 on how to use it safely

Comment: Not your question but FYI the idiomatic way to write your script would be `awk 'NF && !seen[$0]++' filename`.