# Remove lines from a csv file based on column value

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv

I have a csv file with 12 million lines in the following format:

```
mcu_i,INIT,200,iFlash,  11593925,     88347,,0x00092684,r,0x4606b570,   ok,,         32,single,op-c,0,,         0,         0,         0,
mcu_i,INIT,200,iFlash,  11593931,     88348,,0x00092678,r,0x28003801,   ok,,         32,single,op-c,0,,         0,         0,         0,
```

I want to remove lines based on the value of the 6th column with the following logic: if (value >= X AND value <= Y ) => remove lines

I found a solution using gawk:

```
gawk -i inplace -F ',' -v s="$start_marker" -v e="$end_marker" '!($6 <= e && $6 >= s)' myfile.csv
```

but it takes way too long, I would like another solution with better performance.

Thank you

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151825/discussion-on-question-by-raphui-remove-lines-from-a-csv-file-based-on-column-va); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 7):

#### TL;DR

Redirecting your `gawk`'s stdout to `/dev/null` or piping it to `cat` will greatly accelerate it and reduce the runtime significantly.

```
gawk -i inplace [...] myfile.csv >/dev/null
```

Or:

```
gawk -i inplace [...] myfile.csv | cat
```

#### Diving down

Though @RomeoNinov's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/771259/273579) would indeed work faster then your original command, I would like to explain **why** it's faster, and my solution will run just as fast even with `-i inplace`.

If you look at the **Interactive Versus Noninteractive Buffering** section in `gawk` [info pages](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/I_002fO-Functions.html#index-fflush_0028_0029-function), you'll see that:

> Interactive programs generally *line buffer* their output (i.e., they
> write out every line). Noninteractive programs wait until they have a
> full buffer, which may be many lines of output.

It seems this is true even when the result is not printed by `gawk` to stdout, but also when it's printed to some "in place".

#### Example

I have a file with 10 lines.

```
$ cat somefile
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

By default (without making any changes in the file and just printing back all the lines as-is), notice that `strace` shows that `gawk` runs 10 `write` system calls - one for each line in the original file.

```
$ strace -e trace=write -c gawk -i inplace 1 somefile 
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000098           9        10           write
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000098           9        10           total
```

That's because it's an interactive run, and the result is *line buffered* (`gawk` would print each line as soon is it finishes with it, even if the result is being written to a file and not to stdout).

Now, if I redirect stdout to `/dev/null` (or just pipe the command to a `cat` command) to make this command Noninteractive, `strace` shows that `gawk` only calls a single `write` system call. That's because it doesn't print every line immediately, but rather flush the result only once the buffer is full.

```
$ strace -e trace=write -c gawk -i inplace 1 somefile > /dev/null
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000020          20         1           write
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000020          20         1           total
```

This builds up of course, and the bigger your input file is, the larger the difference between interactive and non-interactive runs will be.

#### Summary

Your command is slow because `gawk` in interactive mode writes every line to the file once it finishes processing it. This means it performs millions of writes to the file.

@RomeoNinov's solution is faster than your original command because instead of using `inplace`, it redirects the output to a temporary files, thus it runs in non-interactive mode, which optimizes the buffer flushing and makes `gawk` perform less write operations to the file.

However, you can still use the command provided in your question, but just redirect its stdout to `/dev/null` (since it's empty anyway) or pipe it to `cat`, and it will run just as fast.

##### Security implications of using `gawk` with `inplace`

While I don't fully agree with @RomeoNinov comment that inplace operations might lead to unpredictable results, please notice @OlivierDulac's [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/771255/remove-lines-from-a-csv-file-based-on-column-value#comment1472012_771255) that provides a useful answer explaining why usually using `-i inplace` is considered a security vulnerability and [how to workaround it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/749645/273579) to run it in a safe manner.

Comment: I tried `seq 1000000 > file1m` then tried printing all lines and "modifying" the input file with the output. `time { awk -i inplace '1' file1m; }` output `real    0m11.431s
user    0m0.437s
sys     0m10.828s` while `time { awk '1' file1m > tmp && mv tmp file1m; }` was an order of magnitude faster at `real    0m0.758s
user    0m0.264s
sys     0m0.263s`, i.e. less than 1 second with output to a temp file vs 11 seconds with `-i inplace`.

Comment: FWIW I didn't see a time difference like that with `sed -i -n 'p' file1m` vs `sed -n 'p' file1m > tmp && mv tmp file1m;`

Comment: I contacted the gawk providers about this, see https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2024-02/msg00037.html.

Answer (score 6):

One possible way (via rewriting your command) is:

```
gawk  -F, -v s="$start_marker" -v e="$end_marker" '$6 > e || $6 < s'  myfile.csv >/tmp/newfile
```

In `awk`, it is not recommended practice to use inplace operations, it has security implications. Moreover you can mess up the source file(s) before being 100% sure the script is correct.

Comment: It's better if you show a _complete_ solution, ie using some random file name instead of `/tmp/newfile` (to avoid overriding it if it exists) for instance maybe `myfile.csv.$$`, and renaming it at the end to reach the same result as `inplace`, for instance by adding `&& mv myfile.csv.$$ myfile.csv`.

Comment: @aviro, using "random" filename may lead to fill the target directory in case of emergency stop of program. Static filename may save the disk space and simplify investigation. So every way have own pros and cons :)

Comment: `&& mv myfile.csv.$$ myfile.csv || rm myfile.csv.$$`

Comment: `tmp=$(mktemp) && trap 'rm -f "$tmp"; exit' EXIT && awk '...' file > "$tmp" && mv -- "$tmp" file`.

Comment: @EdMorton, updated. And you are absolute right about negative logic.

Answer (score 1):

If it does not have to be `awk`, then you might try Perl instead:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.18.2;
use warnings;
use strict;

my ($X, $Y) = (88347, 88347);
while (<>) {
    next
        if (/(?:^[^,]*,){5}\s*([^,]+)/ && $1 >= $X && $1 <= $Y);
    print;
}
```

The regular expression skips the first five comma-separated fields in a line, then ignores space, capturing the rest of the 6th field to `$1`.
If the condition matches, the line is ignored; otherwise it's output.

For the example, it would output the line with value 88348.

Use like `perl your_script input_file(s) > output_file`.
Obviously input and output file names should be different!

Answer (score 1):

if you can use tools other than awk, [duckdb](https://duckdb.org/docs/installation) is very quick and convenient.

If your input is

```
mcu_i,INIT,200,iFlash,  11593925,     88347,,0x00092684,r,0x4606b570,   ok,,         32,single,op-c,0,,         0,         0,         0,
mcu_i,INIT,200,iFlash,  11593931,     88348,,0x00092678,r,0x28003801,   ok,,         32,single,op-c,0,,         0,         0,         0,
mcu_i,INIT,200,iFlash,  10593931,     88348,,0x00092678,r,0x28003801,   ok,,         32,single,op-c,0,,         0,         0,         0,
mcu_i,INIT,200,iFlash,  21593931,     98348,,0x00092678,r,0x28003801,   ok,,         32,single,op-c,0,,         0,         0,         0,
mcu_i,INIT,200,iFlash,  31593931,     108348,,0x00092678,r,0x28003801,   ok,,         32,single,op-c,0,,         0,         0,         0,
```

you can run

```
duckdb --csv -c "SELECT * from read_csv_auto('input.csv',HEADER = false,all_varchar=true) 
where NOT
TRY_CAST(TRIM(column05) AS INTEGER) >88348 AND
TRY_CAST(TRIM(column05) AS INTEGER) < 108348;" | tail -n +2 | sed 's/"//g'>outuput.txt
```

to get

```
mcu_i,INIT,200,iFlash,  11593925,     88347,,0x00092684,r,0x4606b570,   ok,,         32,single,op-c,0,,         0,         0,         0,
mcu_i,INIT,200,iFlash,  11593931,     88348,,0x00092678,r,0x28003801,   ok,,         32,single,op-c,0,,         0,         0,         0,
mcu_i,INIT,200,iFlash,  10593931,     88348,,0x00092678,r,0x28003801,   ok,,         32,single,op-c,0,,         0,         0,         0,
```

I have constructed the command in such a way as to leave the strange spaces in your input.

Comment: duckdb looks awesome, thanks. I'm definitely going to try it.

Comment: Have you tried to compare its performance to `awk`, at least in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -MText::CSV -e 'my @rows; my $csv = Text::CSV.new( sep => ",");  \
                        while ($csv.getline($*IN)) -> $row { @rows.push: $row.map(*.trim) if 88000 < $row.[5] < 98000; };  \
                        .join(",").put for @rows;'  <  ~/raphui_771255.csv
```

Raku is a programming language in the Perl-family. It features high-level support for Unicode as well as a powerful Regex engine.

Above answer uses Raku's `Text::CSV` module. The Perl(5) module `Text::CSV_XS` is well-regarded, and a longtime author/maintainer of that module has gone on to develop Raku's `Text::CSV` module (H. Merijn Brand, personal communication).

Sample Input (thanks to @aborruso!):

```
mcu_i,INIT,200,iFlash,  11593925,     88347,,0x00092684,r,0x4606b570,   ok,,         32,single,op-c,0,,         0,         0,         0,
mcu_i,INIT,200,iFlash,  11593931,     88348,,0x00092678,r,0x28003801,   ok,,         32,single,op-c,0,,         0,         0,         0,
mcu_i,INIT,200,iFlash,  10593931,     88348,,0x00092678,r,0x28003801,   ok,,         32,single,op-c,0,,         0,         0,         0,
mcu_i,INIT,200,iFlash,  21593931,     98348,,0x00092678,r,0x28003801,   ok,,         32,single,op-c,0,,         0,         0,         0,
mcu_i,INIT,200,iFlash,  31593931,     108348,,0x00092678,r,0x28003801,   ok,,         32,single,op-c,0,,         0,         0,         0,
```

Sample Output:

```
mcu_i,INIT,200,iFlash,11593925,88347,,0x00092684,r,0x4606b570,ok,,32,single,op-c,0,,0,0,0,
mcu_i,INIT,200,iFlash,11593931,88348,,0x00092678,r,0x28003801,ok,,32,single,op-c,0,,0,0,0,
mcu_i,INIT,200,iFlash,10593931,88348,,0x00092678,r,0x28003801,ok,,32,single,op-c,0,,0,0,0,
```

Note: Raku allows the use of "chained" inequalities. Also, instead of hardcoding the values, Raku has a special associative array `%*ENV` which can be used to access shell variables. So below takes shell variables `startMarker` and `stopMarker` from the environment (i.e. the shell). Use the high level `csv( …, out => $*OUT)` function for output, and your whitespace-containing strings will automatically be quoted (in your case, drop the `.trim` call as well):

```
~$ env startMarker="88000" stopMarker="89000"     \
   raku -MText::CSV -e 'my $start = %*ENV<startMarker>; my $stop =  %*ENV<stopMarker>;     \
                        my @rows; my $csv = Text::CSV.new( sep => ",");    \
                        while ($csv.getline($*IN)) -> $row { @rows.push: $row if $start < $row.[5] < $stop; };    \
                        csv(in => @rows, out => $*OUT);'  <  ~/raphui_771255.csv
mcu_i,INIT,200,iFlash,"  11593925","     88347",,0x00092684,r,0x4606b570,"   ok",,"         32",single,op-c,0,,"         0","         0","         0",
mcu_i,INIT,200,iFlash,"  11593931","     88348",,0x00092678,r,0x28003801,"   ok",,"         32",single,op-c,0,,"         0","         0","         0",
mcu_i,INIT,200,iFlash,"  10593931","     88348",,0x00092678,r,0x28003801,"   ok",,"         32",single,op-c,0,,"         0","         0","         0",
```

https://raku.land/zef:Tux/Text::CSV
https://github.com/Tux/CSV/blob/master/doc/Text-CSV.md
https://docs.raku.org
https://raku.org