# kded taking up X client connections?

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, kde5

So I came up against this error:
[Can't start applications due to "Maximum number of clients reached" error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368017/cant-start-applications-due-to-maximum-number-of-clients-reached-error) 
[How can I diagnose/debug "maximum number of clients reached" X errors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4499/how-can-i-diagnose-debug-maximum-number-of-clients-reached-x-errors)

With help from the above threads I identify kded5 to be the source of the problem (It's the only number that grows with time...)

```
❯ lsof -U +c 15 | cut -f1 -d' ' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -5
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() btrfs file system /var/lib/docker/btrfs
  Output information may be incomplete.
306 Isolated\x20Web
246 Xorg
217 kded5
153 firefox
 69 dbus-daemon
```

The problem is around 2 weeks old. I have to do a reboot every day because I am no longer able to open any new windows. I suppose I could kill that one kded5 process that I see running but I don't know if that's safe. It certainly isn't a long term solution.

How does one go about solving this?

Comment: I have the same issue, identified via https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/700637/11249. I reported it here: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=453280

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm this on KDE neon. It started happening with recent updates. Most definitely a bug so a proper course of action is to report it at:

https://bugs.kde.org/

I suppose only people that leave their desktops running for days or weeks are hit by this bug.

As for kded5 process, it's relatively safe to kill it. It will restart automatically. That is how I have been dealing with this issue.

Comment: `kded5 --replace & disown`