# Replacing /dev/(u)random inside a container

Tags: linux, random, fifo

The */dev/(u)random* devices can be linked from the host into a container.

Can *(u)random* be replaced with a named pipe instead? (assuming some other application (not *(u)random*) provides input to the named pipe)
Or does *(u)random* have any other functionality then being a FIFO-like device and how would such functionality be emulated without creating a new device?

Use case is having (nearly) 100% reproducible runs of applications with full control over *(u)random* inside a container. Having secure random numbers is of no concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pipe wouldn't work because when several processes are reading from the same pipe, it's unpredictable which processes receives which byte. You could use a socket, however. With a socket, the server side gets a separate connection each time a client opens the socket. The server can [query the process at the other end of the socket](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16300/whos-got-the-other-end-of-this-unix-socketpair) which should help predictability as you can make the PRNG seed a function of some process characteristics.

Comment: That link is worth gold, just as a follow up: If the runs wouldn't need to be reproducible and speed was the only concern would a pipe be enough then or is there something missing still?

Comment: @birdybirb With a pipe, another potential is that if there's no reader, the writer gets an end-of-file indication. But this one is solvable: in the writer, keep writing despite the EOF.