# .Xresources key naming and wildcard matching

Tags: xterm, x-resources

**XTerm.vt100.faceName or xterm.vt100.faceName**

Setting `XTerm.vt100.faceName` key in .Xresources does not have any effect,

```
$ xrdb -q
*customization: -color
XTerm.vt100.faceName: Inconsolata:size=14:antialias=true
```

However lowercase `xterm.vt100.faceName` do work

```
$ xrdb -q
*customization: -color
xterm.vt100.faceName: Inconsolata:size=14:antialias=true
```

I'm using a debian netinstall, with XTerm(312) so issue might be is that I'm using a different version of XTerm as discussed in here: ["Xterm" or "xterm" in configuration file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216723/xterm-or-xterm-in-configuration-file)

**Wildcards not working**

For example setting `xterm.vt100.foreground` works but not `*.foreground`

**Update - appres**

- `$ appres XTerm xterm | grep -i color0` when have `*vt100.color0`

  ```
  *vt100.color0:  #1d1f21
  *VT100*color0:  black
  ```
- `$ appres XTerm xterm | grep -i faceName` when have both `XTerm.vt100.faceName` and `xterm.vt100.faceName` merged

  ```
  xterm.vt100.faceName:   Inconsolata:size=14:antialias=true
  XTerm.vt100.faceName:   Inconsolata:size=14:antialias=true
  ```

Comment: I'm puzzled by this one. It works for me. What's the output of `appres XTerm xterm | grep -i facename`? Do you see the same effect with other resources under `vt100`?

Comment: @Gilles please see the updated post

Answer (score 2):

You can check the class of your `xterm` using `xprop` on it. You should see something like

```
$ xprop
...
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "xterm", "XTerm"
```

In your case, more specific settings (less wildcards) seem to work, less specific settings (wildcards, or class name instead of instance name) don't. That's a hint that there are somewhere declarations that `xterm` uses, e.g.

```
xterm*faceName: blah
```

that override your less specific declarations, but are overriden by your more specific declarations.

I'm not entirely sure where `xterm` defines its `Xrm` resources, but the root window properties managed by `xrdb` are just one such source. So if it bothers you that you can't use less specific declarations, you need to find those other declarations on your system, and remove them.

**Edit**: On my Debian systems, application-specific resources seem to be in `/etc/X11/app-defaults`.

Comment: Btw there is no property `faceName` in my `/etc/X11/app-defaults/XTerm`

Comment: It's entirely possible there are other resource files, or even in-built fallbacks, or that `font` settings are an alternative to `faceName`, or ...