# Cinnamon: Which software project "owns" the "Display" configuration dialog?

Tags: x11, process, cinnamon, window

Cinnamon 2.8.8 64-bit, Linux Mint 17.3 'Rosa'

Menu > Preferences > Display

The dialog allows to enable and disable (multiple) monitors, and position them relative to each other with drag and drop.

I don't know if this dialog is specific to Cinnamon. I think I have seen the same dialog in other desktops, such as Gnome or XFCE.

I would like to report a bug for this dialog.

Which project "owns" it and where I would find the issue queue? Thanks :)

(I was first going to post the problem itself here on stackexchange, but I realize this is a bug, and should be reported in an issue queue)

Comment: Report it at https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+filebug

Comment: But this dialog is not specific to Mint, or is it? Will they simply pass it on?

Comment: You should always report an issue on distro packaged software using your distro's bug tracking system, who will then decide whether to pass it upstream or not.  The dialog is part of `/usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/cinnamon-settings.py` which suggests it is very Cinnamon specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `xprop _NET_WM_PID` or `xdotool selectwindow getwindowpid` from a terminal then click on a window to see the process ID of the process that owns that window. (This works often but not always, see [What process created this X11 window?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5478/what-process-created-this-x11-window) for caveats.)

One you have the process ID (e.g. `1234`), `ps -p 1234 -o args` or `ls -l /proc/1234/exe` tells you what command the process is executing. From there, `dpkg -S /path/to/command` tells you what package provides this command.

Comment: Magic!
`python2 /usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/cinnamon-settings.py display` and then `cinnamon-common: /usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/cinnamon-settings.py`. Thanks!

Comment: Ok so this means the team that maintains Cinnamon also maintains this dialog? Or could this simply be re-branded?

Comment: @donquixote Yes, that means that this dialog is part of Cinnamon. I don't know what you mean by “re-branded”; the program comes from the Cinnamon package, historically that's a fork of Gnome but I don't see a similar file in Gnome so that program appears to have been added after the fork.