# Find the processes making a window

Tags: linux, process, window

OS: Manjaro Linux x86_64,
Kernel: 5.10.84-1-MANJARO,
DE: Cinnamon 5.0.7

Everytime I start my computer and log in, there is a 1x1 unnamed window with a settings cog icon, at first I ignored it, but now I'm getting suspicious of this window (as in, malicious kind of suspicious).

I've tried identifying what PID it has using `xdotool getwindowpid` which returns

```
[xproot@xproot-lappy ~]$ xdotool getwindowpid 65011715
window 65011715 has no pid associated with it.
```

I also tried `xprop _NET_WM_PID | sed 's/_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = //'` which returns

```
_NET_WM_PID:  not found.
```

now both of these commands work with regular windows, yet it doesn't work with this? just adds more suspicion to me.
Anyone could bring up a solution? How to find what is making this window? I originally thought it was kde-connect-indicator since it started appearing as soon I added that to startup applications but removing it from it doesn't help.

Comment: It's unlikely to be malware: why would malware bother to create a window at all? And make it visible? Creating a visible window doesn't give it any additional privileges. Querying `_NET_WM_PID` relies on the application setting it, which many do but not all.

Comment: Well even if it wasn't malware I'd love to get rid of it, it gets annoying having to close it, btw https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5478/what-process-created-this-x11-window DOES NOT HELP in this occasion, none of the parents or children have associated PIDs

Comment: Sure, there are no parents to query. You'll have to use the complicated method with gdb.