# "This computer has only 0 bytes disk remaining" message from Linux running on Virtual box

Tags: virtualbox, disk-usage, manjaro

This is the setup. I started seeing this message today from Linux Manjaro installed on Virtual box under windows 10.  The issue is that I have lots of disk space, both allocated for the Linux and also for windows 10 itself and for the mounted disk in Linux so I can access my windows files from Linux.

So I do not understand what causes this message to come up.

[image]

On Linux this is the output of `df -H`

```
>df -H /
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        68G   37G   28G  58% /
```

And

```
>df -H
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
dev              23G     0   23G   0% /dev
run              23G  1.1M   23G   1% /run
/dev/sda1        68G   43G   22G  67% /
tmpfs            23G   25k   23G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            23G  4.8G   18G  22% /tmp
tmpfs           4.5G  115k  4.5G   1% /run/user/1000
public_html     4.1T  1.1T  3.0T  26% /mnt/g/public_html
```

And

```
sudo du -s -h -x /*
0   /bin
76M /boot
20K /desktopfs-pkgs.txt
0   /dev
14M /etc
11G /home
0   /lib
0   /lib64
16K /lost+found
8.0K    /mnt
793M    /opt
du: cannot read directory '/proc/520610/task/520610/net': Invalid argument
du: cannot read directory '/proc/520610/net': Invalid argument
du: cannot read directory '/proc/520665/task/520665/net': Invalid argument
du: cannot read directory '/proc/520665/net': Invalid argument
du: cannot access '/proc/520912/task/520912/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/520912/task/520912/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/520912/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/520912/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
0   /proc
328K    /root
8.0K    /rootfs-pkgs.txt
1.1M    /run
0   /sbin
12K /srv
0   /sys
4.4G    /tmp
18G /usr
5.3G    /var
>
```

I am running latest Manjaro, MATE desktop version (not xfce).

```
lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    n/a
Distributor ID: ManjaroLinux
Description:    Manjaro Linux
Release:    22.0.5
Codename:   Sikaris
```

The last entry above is on /mnt/g` which is windows.  As you can see there is lots of free space, right?

The other strange thing, is that I am running a long script on Linux to compile files (it is running on the windows disk) and it is still running with no errors and no problems.

This is also the Virtual Box setting for this Linux virtual machine. I allocated 64 GB disk for it when I created it. (I requested the whole space be pre-allocated instead of the other option of dynamic expansion)

[image]

The Virtual Box I am running is 6.1.34.

On my PC, I have tons of free space on C:\ where the Virtual box lives and on G:\ which is the disk mounted from linux. I have 1.22 TB free space on `C:\` and 2.7 TB free space on `G:\`

[image]

Here is the actual .vdi file (virtual box) on windows

[image]
I also checked `/var/log` on Linux to see if there is a log file which might contain more information, but there is no log file updated as of today March 27, 2023 which is when I just got this pop-up window message

```
>pwd
/var/log
>ls -lrt
total 180
drwx------  2 root root             4096 Apr 21  2022 audit
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root             4096 Jun  6  2022 gssproxy
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root             4096 Jun 10  2022 cups
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root             4096 Oct 19 09:12 old
drwx------  2 root root             4096 Jan  4 04:56 private
-rw-rw-r--  1 root utmp                0 Feb  6 23:08 lastlog
-rw-rw----  1 root utmp                0 Feb  6 23:08 btmp.1
drwxr-sr-x+ 4 root systemd-journal  4096 Feb  6 23:12 journal
-rw-rw----  1 root utmp                0 Mar  1 00:00 btmp
-rw-r--r--  1 root root            71354 Mar 26 11:55 pacman.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root root            24980 Mar 26 11:55 Xorg.0.log.old
drwx--x--x  2 root lightdm          4096 Mar 26 11:57 lightdm
-rw-rw-r--  1 root utmp            14592 Mar 26 11:57 wtmp
-rw-r--r--  1 root root            24799 Mar 26 16:29 Xorg.0.log
```

I do not know which application on Linux is actually producing this pop-up message about low disk space. If I can find the application which generated this message, this will help find what is going on.

Any idea what causes this message? is it Linux getting confused, or Virtual box problem?

if there is additional information I can give please let me know.

Fyi, I just [added question](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/this-computer-has-only-0-bytes-disk-remaining-message-from-manjaro-on-virtual-box/137149) on this at Manjaro foum asking if someone knows which application on Manjaro generated this message.

**Update**

Here is the info requested

```
>sudo parted /dev/sda unit MiB print
[sudo] password for me: 

Model: ATA VBOX HARDDISK (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 65536MiB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start    End       Size      Type     File system  Flags
 1      1.00MiB  65531MiB  65530MiB  primary  ext4         boot
```

And

```
>sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 64 GiB, 68719476736 bytes, 134217728 sectors
Disk model: VBOX HARDDISK   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x47f9fdb6

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 134207009 134204962  64G 83 Linux
>
```

btw, someone at the Manjaro forum said this message could be generated by "Free Space Notifier" service. But I am still unable to find if this is running or what it is.

I found similar question for Ubuntu [the-volume-filesystem-root-has-only-0-bytes-disk-space-remaining](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73867/the-volume-filesystem-root-has-only-0-bytes-disk-space-remaining) but unlike the above where the system was really low on space, mine is not.

**Update**

Added info requested

```
>df -Thi
Filesystem     Type     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
dev            devtmpfs   5.3M   451  5.3M    1% /dev
run            tmpfs      5.3M   638  5.3M    1% /run
/dev/sda1      ext4       4.0M  794K  3.3M   20% /
tmpfs          tmpfs      5.3M     7  5.3M    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs      1.0M  131K  894K   13% /tmp
tmpfs          tmpfs      1.1M   113  1.1M    1% /run/user/1000
public_html    vboxsf     1000 -976K  977K     - /mnt/g/public_html
```

### Update 3/29/2023

Now I am getting message that it has only 841 MB disk remaining

[image]

But why?

```
>df -H
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
dev              23G     0   23G   0% /dev
run              23G  1.1M   23G   1% /run
/dev/sda1        68G   37G   28G  58% /
tmpfs            23G   25k   23G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            23G  4.8G   18G  22% /tmp
tmpfs           4.5G  123k  4.5G   1% /run/user/1000
public_html     4.1T  1.1T  3.0T  26% /mnt/g/public_html
```

Comment: @roaima fyi, info added. btw, I just got another pop-up message shown also.

Comment: Does this cause any real problem? sounds like you could just tick that ignore box and carry on.
you can try using `xwininfo` and `xprop` to get the parent process' PID as in [What process created this X11 window?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5478)

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned, this does _not_ seem to be causing an issue that I could see. but I am not 100% sure. This is why I asked.  But this could be due to a bug in Manjaro also. The popup message keeps coming up every 1 or 2 hrs it seems. Thanks for the hint on how to find who created the window message.

Comment: do you have one or more processes filling up /tmp or one of the other tmpfs mounts? do you have lots of files, using up all available inodes? (run `df -Thi` to check).  Do you have filesystem quotas enabled (either in linux or whatever the equivalent is in windows)?    Finally "zero disk space" may not necessarily mean zero disk space - some (badly written) programs interpret almost **ANY** write error as "disk full".

Comment: @cas added info. I only have one program running, which uses sagemath software to do some computations. Nothing else. **Do you have filesystem quotas enabled** I have no idea. I never modify such settings, whatever the default Linux installation is, is what I have. Same for windows 10.  But as you can see, I have lots of disk space everywhere. Not even close to being full./

Comment: seems pretty normal except for only 1000 inodes and `-976K` IUsed for public_html. that seems odd. maybe a bug in the virtual box modules?  and just "public_html" rather than "/public_html" seems odd too (but that may be normal for vboxsf. dunno, i use KVM rather than virtual box for my VMs).

Comment: maybe check the man page for vboxfs (or mount.vboxfs, or look in the vbox dir under /usr/share/doc if there is one)....there may be a mount option to increase the number of inodes in the virtual fs.   Or maybe inodes just aren't relevant to vboxsf.

Comment: @cas the `public_html` is the windows disk mounted from Linux.  The mount point is /mnt/g. This is on the G:\ drive on windows. Lots of empty space there also. It seems this error message not causing any problem. I got it few times so far, and just close it and nothing happens. My program is still running with no issues. So have no idea what it is complaining about.

Comment: @cas I mount the vboxsf using the same command I always used, which is `mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=1000 public_html /mnt/g/public_html` which I've used for years on different Linux virtual box installations, and never got any problems. I know nothing about increasing inodes and all that.

Comment: yeah, i guessed that's what it was.   FYI inodes are a separate resource from disk space.  they're a kind of metadata resource for files, sockets, named pipes, directories, device nodes, etc.  It's possible to run out of inodes while still having lots of space available, and vice-versa (the latter is far more common).   1000 is a very low number of inodes for a filesystem, which is why i suspect it might not be relevant to vboxsf. or it might be a bug. or a configurable mount option.